# String concatenation: concat() vs "+" operator

Tags: java, string, concatenation

Assuming String a and b:

```
a += b
a = a.concat(b)
```

Under the hood, are they the same thing?

Here is concat decompiled as reference. I'd like to be able to decompile the `+` operator as well to see what that does.

```
public String concat(String s) {

    int i = s.length();
    if (i == 0) {
        return this;
    }
    else {
        char ac[] = new char[count + i];
        getChars(0, count, ac, 0);
        s.getChars(0, i, ac, count);
        return new String(0, count + i, ac);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

Comment: I'm not sure `+` can be decompiled.

Comment: Use *javap* to disassemble a Java class file.

Comment: Due to 'immutability' you should probably be using `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`-(thread unsafe thus faster, instead

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/concatenating-strings-in-java-9

Answer (score 649, accepted):

No, not quite.

Firstly, there's a slight difference in semantics. If `a` is `null`, then `a.concat(b)` throws a `NullPointerException` but `a+=b` will treat the original value of `a` as if it were `null`. Furthermore, the `concat()` method only accepts `String` values while the `+` operator will silently convert the argument to a String (using the `toString()` method for objects). So the `concat()` method is more strict in what it accepts.

To look under the hood, write a simple class with `a += b;`

```
public class Concat {
    String cat(String a, String b) {
        a += b;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Now disassemble with `javap -c` (included in the Sun JDK). You should see a listing including:

```
java.lang.String cat(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   7:   aload_1
   8:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   11:  aload_2
   12:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   15:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/    String;
   18:  astore_1
   19:  aload_1
   20:  areturn
```

So, `a += b` is the equivalent of

```
a = new StringBuilder()
    .append(a)
    .append(b)
    .toString();
```

The `concat` method should be faster. However, with more strings the `StringBuilder` method wins, at least in terms of performance.

The source code of `String` and `StringBuilder` (and its package-private base class) is available in src.zip of the Sun JDK. You can see that you are building up a char array (resizing as necessary) and then throwing it away when you create the final `String`. In practice memory allocation is surprisingly fast.

**Update:** As Pawel Adamski notes, performance has changed in more recent HotSpot. `javac` still produces exactly the same code, but the bytecode compiler cheats. Simple testing entirely fails because the entire body of code is thrown away. Summing `System.identityHashCode` (not `String.hashCode`) shows the `StringBuffer` code has a slight advantage. Subject to change when the next update is released, or if you use a different JVM. From [@lukaseder](https://twitter.com/lukaseder), [a list of HotSpot JVM intrinsics](https://gist.github.com/apangin/7a9b7062a4bd0cd41fcc).

Comment: @HyperLink You can see the code using `javap -c` on a compiled class that uses it. (Oh, as in the answer. You just need to interpret the bytecode disassembly, which shouldn't be that difficult.)

Comment: You can consult the [JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/) to understand the individual bytecodes.  The stuff you'd want to reference is in chapter 6.  A bit obscure, but you can get the gist of it fairly easily.

Comment: I wonder why the Java compiler uses `StringBuilder` even when joining two strings? If `String` included static methods to concatenate up to four strings, or all the strings in a `String[]`, code could append up to four strings with two object allocations (the result `String` and its backing `char[]`, neither one redundant), and any number of strings with three allocations (the `String[]`, the result `String`, and the backing `char[]`, with only the first being redundant). As it is, using `StringBuilder` will *at best* require four allocations, and will require copying every character twice.

Comment: That expression, a+=b. Doesn't it mean: a=a+b?

Comment: @user132522 Yes. (Although with other types there may be casting involved.)

Comment: How does it have to do with concatenation? You mean a being a string object, and b is of other type. So b gets forced to become a string object?

Comment: Is this what you mean by casting? I am at elementary lvl. I usually use the word "casting" for converting between int and double(truncation).

Comment: @user132522 For types such as `short` the result of `+` would be `int` (because that's the sort of weird thing Java does). So `a = a + b;` would not compile as you can't assign an `int` to a `short`. `a += b;` would silently cast back to `short`.

Comment: So int = short + short will not compiled. But b/c the shorthand cast the int result to short. In the format short+=short, the same expression will compile. Am I understanding it right?

Comment: About that StringBuilder is better than concat: Correct me if i am wrong, but StringBuilder, and others of his kind allocates 2x the memory for receiving new content that exceeds the capacity need. Building SQL querys i got several times an error, for this reason in tests, and i solved using ´concat´, was a little bit les confortable but the memory was good.

Comment: Things have changed since when this answer was created. Please read my answer bellow.

Comment: Could u elaborate more about "bytecode compiler cheats" part?

Comment: Things have changed since this answer was updated.  I don't believe there's any scenario remaining in which `StringBuilder` or `concat` beat `+` due to [JEP 280](https://openjdk.org/jeps/280).

Answer (score 103):

[Niyaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47615/662581) is correct, but it's also worth noting that the special + operator can be converted into something more efficient by the Java compiler.  Java has a StringBuilder class which represents a non-thread-safe, mutable String.  When performing a bunch of String concatenations, the Java compiler silently converts

```
String a = b + c + d;
```

into

```
String a = new StringBuilder(b).append(c).append(d).toString();
```

which for large strings is significantly more efficient.  As far as I know, this does not happen when you use the concat method.

However, the concat method is more efficient when concatenating an empty String onto an existing String.  In this case, the JVM does not need to create a new String object and can simply return the existing one.  See [the concat documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) to confirm this.

So if you're super-concerned about efficiency then you should use the concat method when concatenating possibly-empty Strings, and use + otherwise.  However, the performance difference should be negligible and you probably shouldn't ever worry about this.

Comment: concat infact doesn't do that.  I've edited my post with a decompilation of the concat method

Comment: infact it does. Look a the first lines of your concat code. The problem with concat is that it always generates a new String()

Comment: @MarcioAguiar: maybe you mean that + always generates a new `String` - as you say, `concat` has one exception when you concat an empty `String`.

Answer (score 52):

I ran a similar test as @marcio but with the following loop instead:

```
String c = a;
for (long i = 0; i < 100000L; i++) {
    c = c.concat(b); // make sure javac cannot skip the loop
    // using c += b for the alternative
}
```

Just for good measure, I threw in `StringBuilder.append()` as well.  Each test was run 10 times, with 100k reps for each run.  Here are the results:

- `StringBuilder` wins hands down.  The clock time result was 0 for most the runs, and the longest took 16ms.
- `a += b` takes about 40000ms (40s) for each run.
- `concat` only requires 10000ms (10s) per run.

I haven't decompiled the class to see the internals or run it through profiler yet, but I suspect `a += b` spends much of the time creating new objects of `StringBuilder` and then converting them back to `String`.

Comment: Object creation time really matters. That's why in many situations we use StringBuilder directly rather than taking advantage of the StringBuilder behind +.

Comment: @coolcfan: When `+` is used for two strings, are there any cases where using `StringBuilder` is better than would be `String.valueOf(s1).concat(s2)`?  Any idea why compilers wouldn't use the latter [or else omit the `valueOf` call in cases where `s1` is known to be non-null]?

Comment: @supercat sorry I don't know. Maybe people who are behind this sugar are the best ones to answer this.

Comment: Search for: invokedynamic StringConcatFactory

Answer (score 39):

Most answers here are from 2008. It looks that things have changed over the time.  My latest benchmarks made with JMH shows that on Java 8 `+` is around two times faster than `concat`.

My benchmark:

```
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 200, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 200, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
public class StringConcatenation {

    @org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class State2 {
        public String a = "abc";
        public String b = "xyz";
    }

    @org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class State3 {
        public String a = "abc";
        public String b = "xyz";
        public String c = "123";
    }


    @org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class State4 {
        public String a = "abc";
        public String b = "xyz";
        public String c = "123";
        public String d = "!@#";
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void plus_2(State2 state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(state.a+state.b);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void plus_3(State3 state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(state.a+state.b+state.c);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void plus_4(State4 state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(state.a+state.b+state.c+state.d);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void stringbuilder_2(State2 state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(new StringBuilder().append(state.a).append(state.b).toString());
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void stringbuilder_3(State3 state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(new StringBuilder().append(state.a).append(state.b).append(state.c).toString());
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void stringbuilder_4(State4 state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(new StringBuilder().append(state.a).append(state.b).append(state.c).append(state.d).toString());
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void concat_2(State2 state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(state.a.concat(state.b));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void concat_3(State3 state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(state.a.concat(state.b.concat(state.c)));
    }


    @Benchmark
    public void concat_4(State4 state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(state.a.concat(state.b.concat(state.c.concat(state.d))));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Benchmark                             Mode  Cnt         Score         Error  Units
StringConcatenation.concat_2         thrpt   50  24908871.258 ± 1011269.986  ops/s
StringConcatenation.concat_3         thrpt   50  14228193.918 ±  466892.616  ops/s
StringConcatenation.concat_4         thrpt   50   9845069.776 ±  350532.591  ops/s
StringConcatenation.plus_2           thrpt   50  38999662.292 ± 8107397.316  ops/s
StringConcatenation.plus_3           thrpt   50  34985722.222 ± 5442660.250  ops/s
StringConcatenation.plus_4           thrpt   50  31910376.337 ± 2861001.162  ops/s
StringConcatenation.stringbuilder_2  thrpt   50  40472888.230 ± 9011210.632  ops/s
StringConcatenation.stringbuilder_3  thrpt   50  33902151.616 ± 5449026.680  ops/s
StringConcatenation.stringbuilder_4  thrpt   50  29220479.267 ± 3435315.681  ops/s
```

Comment: I wonder why Java `String` never included a static function to form a string by concatenating the elements of a `String[]`.  Using `+` to concatenate 8 strings using such a function would require constructing and later abandoning `String[8]`, but that would be the only object that would need to be constructed abandoned, while using a `StringBuilder` would require constructing and abandoning `StringBuilder` instance and *at least* one `char[]` backing store.

Comment: @supercat Some static `String.join()` methods were added in Java 8, as quick syntax wrappers around the `java.util.StringJoiner` class.

Comment: @TiStrga: Has the handling of `+` changed to use such functions?

Comment: @supercat That would break binary backwards compatibility, so no.  It was merely in reply to your "why String never included a static function" comment:  now there _is_ such a function.  The rest of your proposal (refactoring `+` to use it) would require more than what the Java devs are willing to change, sadly.

Comment: @TiStrga: Is there any way a Java bytecode file can indicate "If function X is available, call it; otherwise do something else" in a way that could be resolved in the process of loading a class?  Generating code with a static method that can either chain to Java's static method or else use a stringbuilder if that isn't available would seem the optimal solution.

Comment: Could u tell me why `+` is fast 2x than `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Things have changed again since Java 9. Please update.

Answer (score 22):

Tom is correct in describing exactly what the + operator does.  It creates a temporary `StringBuilder`, appends the parts, and finishes with `toString()`.

However, all of the answers so far are ignoring the effects of HotSpot runtime optimizations.  Specifically, these temporary operations are recognized as a common pattern and are replaced with more efficient machine code at run-time.

@marcio: You've created a [micro-benchmark](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225.html); with modern JVM's this is not a valid way to profile code.

The reason run-time optimization matters is that many of these differences in code -- even including object-creation -- are completely different once HotSpot gets going.  The only way to know for sure is profiling your code *in situ*.

Finally, all of these methods are in fact incredibly fast.  This might be a case of premature optimization.  If you have code that concatenates strings a lot, the way to get maximum speed probably has nothing to do with which operators you choose and instead the algorithm you're using!

Comment: I guess by "these temporary operations" you mean the use of escape analysis to allocate "heap" objects on the stack where provable correct. Although escape analysis is present in HotSpot (useful for removing some synchronisation), I don't believe it, is at the time of writing, u

Comment: While this topic is interesting, I really think the mention of "premature optimization" is important. Don't spend too much time on this issue if you're not sure this piece of code is actually taking an important proportion of the total computation time!

Answer (score 21):

How about some simple testing? Used the code below:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

String a = "a";

String b = "b";

for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { //ten million times
     String c = a.concat(b);
}

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println(end - start);
```

- The `"a + b"` version executed in **2500ms**.
- The `a.concat(b)` executed in **1200ms**.

Tested several times. The `concat()` version execution took half of the time on average.

This result surprised me because the `concat()` method always creates a new string (it returns a "`new String(result)`". It's well known that:

```
String a = new String("a") // more than 20 times slower than String a = "a"
```

Why wasn't the compiler capable of optimize the string creation in "a + b" code, knowing the it always resulted in the same string? It could avoid a new string creation.
If you don't believe the statement above, test for your self.

Comment: I tested on java jdk1.8.0_241 your code, For me the "a+b" code is giving optimized results. With concat(): **203ms** and with "+": **113ms** . I guess in previous release it wasn't that optimized.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, there are two important differences between + and the `concat` method.

1. If you are using the **concat** method then you would only be able to concatenate strings while in case of the **+** operator, you can also concatenate the string with any data type.

   **For Example:**

   ```
   String s = 10 + "Hello";
   ```

   In this case, the output should be **10Hello**.

   ```
   String s = "I";
   String s1 = s.concat("am").concat("good").concat("boy");
   System.out.println(s1);
   ```

   In the above case you have to provide two strings mandatory.
2. The second and main difference between **+** and **concat** is that:

   **Case 1:**
   Suppose I concat the same strings with **concat** operator in this way

   ```
   String s="I";
   String s1=s.concat("am").concat("good").concat("boy");
   System.out.println(s1);
   ```

   In this case total number of objects created in the pool are 7 like this:

   ```
   I
   am
   good
   boy
   Iam
   Iamgood
   Iamgoodboy
   ```

   **Case 2:**

   Now I am going to concatinate the same strings via **+** operator

   ```
   String s="I"+"am"+"good"+"boy";
   System.out.println(s);
   ```

   In the above case total number of objects created are only 5.

   Actually when we concatinate the strings via **+** operator then it maintains a StringBuffer class to perform the same task as follows:-

   ```
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("I");
   sb.append("am");
   sb.append("good");
   sb.append("boy");
   System.out.println(sb);
   ```

   In this way it will create only five objects.

So guys these are the basic differences between **+** and the **concat** method.
Enjoy :)

Comment: My dear, You know very well that any string literal treated as an String object itself which stores in String pool.So in this case we have 4 string literals .So obviously at least 4 objects should be created in pool.

Comment: I don't think so: `String s="I"+"am"+"good"+"boy";
        String s2 = "go".concat("od");
        System.out.println(s2 == s2.intern());` prints `true`, which means `"good"` was not in the string pool before calling `intern()`

Comment: I am talking only about this line String s="I"+"am"+"good"+"boy";
In this case all 4 are string literals are kept in a pool.Hence 4 objects should be created in pool.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, I wanted to add that the definition of the '+' operator can be found in the [JLS SE8 15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> *If only one operand expression is of type String, then string
> conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a
> string at run time.*
>
> *The result of string concatenation is a reference to a String object
> that is the concatenation of the two operand strings. The characters
> of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the right-hand
> operand in the newly created string.*
>
> *The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a
> constant expression (§15.28)*

About the implementation the JLS says the following:

> *An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation
> in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate
> String object. To increase the performance of repeated string
> concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a
> similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects
> that are created by evaluation of an expression.*
>
> *For primitive types, an implementation may also optimize away the
> creation of a wrapper object by converting directly from a primitive
> type to a string.*

So judging from the 'a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a similar technique to reduce', different compilers could produce different byte-code.

Answer (score 3):

The **+ operator** can work between a string and a string, char, integer, double or float data type value. It just converts the value to its string representation before concatenation.

The **concat operator** can only be done on and with strings. It checks for data type compatibility and throws an error, if they don't match.

Except this, the code you provided does the same stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.

`a.concat(b)` is implemented in String and I think the implementation didn't change much since early java machines. The `+` operation implementation depends on Java version and compiler. Currently `+` is implemented using [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) to make the operation as fast as possible. Maybe in the future, this will change. In earlier versions of java `+` operation on Strings was much slower as it produced intermediate results.

I guess that `+=` is implemented using `+` and similarly optimized.

Comment: "Currently + is implemented using StringBuffer"
False

It's StringBuilder. 

StringBuffer is the threadsafe impl of StringBuilder.

Comment: It used to be StringBuffer prior to java 1.5, as that was the version when StringBuilder was first introduced.

Comment: When you say "currently" which JDK do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

When using +, the speed decreases as the string's length increases, but when using concat, the speed is more stable, and the best option is using the StringBuilder class which has stable speed in order to do that.

I guess you can understand why. But the totally best way for creating long strings is using StringBuilder() and append(), either speed will be unacceptable.

Comment: using the + operator is equivalent to using the StringBuilder (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

Comment: @ihebiheb or `StringBuffer`

Comment: @ihebiheb "The implementation of the string concatenation operator is left to the discretion of a Java compiler, as long as the compiler ultimately conforms to The Java™ Language Specification. For example, the javac compiler *may* implement the operator with StringBuffer, StringBuilder, or java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory depending on the JDK version (...)."
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

Note that `s.concat("hello");` would result in a `NullPointereException` when s is null. In Java, the behavior of the + operator is usually determined by the left operand:

`System.out.println(3 + 'a'); //100`

However, Strings are an exception. If either operand is a String, the result is expected to be a String. This is the reason null is converted into "null", even though you might expect a `RuntimeException`.