# Difference between string.concat() and + operator

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference between String concat and the + operator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693597/is-there-a-difference-between-string-concat-and-the-operator-in-java)

Is there any difference between:

```
String A = "Hello";
String B = A.concat("Testing");
```

and

```
String A = "Hello";
String B = A + "Testing";
```

Yes i know there ain't any difference in the output. Wanted to know if there is any technical difference. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in this example.

If you concatenate several strings with + (e.g., `"Hello " + user + "!"`), current compilers will use a [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to implement the + operator because this is faster than first creating the string for `"Hello " + user` and then creating the final string. They probably don't do that for `concat()`, so there would be a technical difference here.

**Edit**: see also [String concatenation: concat() vs "+" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/java-string-concatenation) and [Is there a difference between String concat and the + operator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693597/is-there-a-difference-between-string-concat-and-the-operator-in-java).

Comment: `concat` only accepts one string to concatenate anyway, so representing `"Hello" + user + "!"` via `concat` would be cumbersome. I'm fairly sure, though, that .NET's `String.Concat(params String[])` uses a `StringBuilder` as that's what the compiler turns `+` into.