# Java - Access variable inside and outside of for-loop

Tags: java, variables, loops, for-loop

```
String playerlist;

for(Player p : allplayers){
    playerlist += p.getDisplayName() + ", ";
}

sendMessage(playerlist);
```

How can I accomplish this? I need to have a variable inside my for-loop, and then access it outside of the loop.

Thanks, and sorry if this is a very nooby question. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: the code you've posted already does that, what do you need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close.  You need to change the first line to

```
String playerlist = "";
```

In Java it's illegal to use a variable before it's initialized, and the line

```
playerlist += p.getDisplayName() + ", ";
```

desugars(*) to

```
String temp = playerlist;
playerlist = temp + (p.getDisplayName() + ", ");
```

Once you initialize `playerlist`, you are able to read off its contents into the temporary variable, and then update `playerlist`.

There are two higher-level suggestions, though.

1. If you have a join method available, as some libraries provide (as do the the [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) and [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) platforms), you can just use a join, which is easier to read.
2. However, if you don't have a join method available (AFAIK, the Java standard library provides no such thing), you should use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), consistent with @anubhava's suggestion.  You'll get better performance on large numbers of strings, and the code is easier to understand, which is a win-win.

---

EDIT: As @edalorzo rightly mentions in the comments, you will only get an error for not initializing a *local* variable, and both static and instance fields are automatically initialized.  Specifically, numeric types (`int`, `long`, `double`, etc.) are initialized to 0, booleans are initialized to `false`, and reference types are initialized to `null`.

The spec explicitly describes the automatic initialization of fields, so you can rely on it, but it's rarely what you want.  Normally, you will want a non-default value of the field when you use it later, since `null` isn't terribly useful (and many languages, particularly functional languages like Standard ML, go without `null` altogether).  So I would recommend initializing all the fields of your objects in the constructor.

---

(*):  The "desugaring" I show above is almost accurate: in truth, `playerlist` is evaluated only once, which doesn't affect the behavior of this particular program.

Comment: WOW that was easy, thanks so much :D I thought I tried every combination, I guess I forgot one :) I will accept as best answer once it lets me (12 mins).

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that only local variables require explicit initialization as stated in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5). Since class and instance variables are explicitly initialized and parameters receive a value through their corresponding argument.

Answer (score 6):

If you initialize your variable outside loop you can get that:

```
String playerlist = "";
```

But since you are manipulating Strings it will be much better to use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of String. Reason is the String is immutable and you will be creating a new String in each iteration inside for loop. However StringBuilder is mutable and has various overloaded `append` methods to support your operation. Using StringBuilder your code will become like this:

```
StringBuilder playerlist = new StringBuilder();

for (Player p : allplayers) {
    playerlist.append(p.getDisplayName()).append(", ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The local variable `playerlist` may not have been initialized. In java `for` loop statement,local variables must first initialize and then use in loop block. You have to initialize `playerlist`. You can use following code:

```
String playerlist = null;

for(Player p : allplayers)
{
    playerlist += p.getDisplayName() + ", ";
}

sendMessage(playerlist);
```

But it is better use following code:

```
StringBuilder playerlist = new StringBuilder();

for(Player p : allplayers)
{
    playerlist.append(p.getDisplayName()).append(", ");
}
sendMessage(playerlist.toString());
```

Comment: -1 Initializing `playerlist` to `null` will cause incorrect behavior (the literal string "null" at the beginning of the resulting string).  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/693617/960195.

Comment: `playList` local variable may be empty so a String variable instantiated un-useful. In this sample `sendMessage` method has to check `null` state of incoming value.