# Troubles with variable scope outside the for loop

Tags: java, scope

So, there is a class `Hotel`, that contains 20 Rooms in form of a matrix 4x5 (4 floors, 5 rooms on every floor).  The class `Room` has the properties:

```
floorNumber(int),  
roomNumber(int),  
numberOfBeds(int),  
occupation(boolean)
etc.
```

For `occupation`, true means busy, and false means free.

One of methods I have to implement in Hotel is the one that reserves a room

```
reserve(int floorNumber, int roomNumber)
```

This method should check if occupation is true or false.
If it is true, then reservation fails, and if it is false, I should set occupation to true, with method

```
setOccupation(boolean t).
```

Also, method `reserve` return boolean (true or false), depending on whether reservation succeeded or not.
In that method, you guess, is problem with scope of one variable.
So there it is:

```
public boolean reserve(int floorNumber, int roomNumber){
    boolean flag = false;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      if(rooms[floorNumber][i].getRoomNumber() == roomNumber){//every element in matrix rooms has this property: rooms[floorNumber][some_number_from_1_to_5]
        if (rooms[floorNumber][i].getOccupancy() == false){
          rooms[floorNumber][i].setOccupancy(true);
          flag = true;
        }
        else
          flag = false;
      }
    }
    return flag;
  }
```

The problem is, when I set (in first line) flag to true, function returns true, and when I set flag to false, function returns false.
The reason I have to assign *some* value to flag in first line is because compiler shows:

```
Error: variable flag might not have been initialized
```

So, the problem is that it seems like method never executes code with for loop.
I know that variables defined in loop don't exist outside loop, but those defined outside should change their values in loop.
Like in this question here:
[Java - Access variable inside and outside of for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407505/java-access-variable-inside-and-outside-of-for-loop)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. `boolean flag false;` is invalid. Fix that statement, and recompile.

Comment: Sorry, I edited queston, it does compile now. Originally, it says `boolean flag = false;`

Comment: Why are you doing a loop here anyway? It is a 4 x 5 array. You know the floor and room number (e.g., 2, 3). Get the room from the rooms array directly (e.g., Room room = rooms[2][3]).

Comment: @RealSkeptic you're right. I misread the question. Sorry.

Comment: @LazyLady use your debugger, and execute your code step by step. If it never changes the flag, there is a simple explanation: the expression `rooms[floorNumber][i].getRoomNumber() == roomNumber` is never true.

Comment: @KevinO Rooms can't have same numbers on every floor, so number in another brackets is not room number.

Comment: @JB Nizet I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was.
It was actually index `floorNumber` in matrix `rooms[floorNumber][]` that goes from 0 to 3 (there are 4 floors), of course.
But in real life, floor numbers go from 1, and I passed argument to

`reserve(int floorNumber,int roomNumber)`

without considering that.
So, I just decremented floorNumber by 1 in body of method, and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to accomplish what you want to do. You don't need a boolean flag at all; you can just return true immediately on success or return false if the entire loop executed without finding a room.

```
public boolean reserve(int floorNumber, int roomNumber){
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //every element in matrix rooms has this property:
    //rooms[floorNumber][some_number_from_1_to_5]
    if (rooms[floorNumber][i].getRoomNumber() == roomNumber){
      if (rooms[floorNumber][i].getOccupancy() == false){
        rooms[floorNumber][i].setOccupancy(true);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

---

But if you insist on applying your original approach that uses a flag, then: First give it a value of false (in case no room succeeded). When we find an unoccupied room (successful), set it to true. If we find an occupied room, **don't touch the flag value**.

```
public boolean reserve(int floorNumber, int roomNumber){
  boolean flag = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //every element in matrix rooms has this property:
    //rooms[floorNumber][some_number_from_1_to_5]
    if (rooms[floorNumber][i].getRoomNumber() == roomNumber){
      if (rooms[floorNumber][i].getOccupancy() == false){
        rooms[floorNumber][i].setOccupancy(true);
        flag = true;
      } // else DO NOTHING
    }
  }
  return flag;
}
```

Comment: When I do that, compiler says:
`1 error found:
Error: missing return statement`

Comment: @LazyLady: Sorry, I missed one level of braces. Fixed now.