# Java += operator on String with charAt() methods results in char addition

Tags: java, string, operators, charat

I'm working through the problems on Codingbat.com and bumped into the fact that for the `+=` operator, `a += b` isn't necessarily exactly equal to `a = a + b`. This is well known and has been discussed on SO before, but I bumped into something strange happening when using the `charAt()` method combined with the above syntax that I can't make sense of.

Say I have two variables:

```
String str    = "The";
String result = "";
```

I want to add the first letter in "str" two times to "result". One way of doing this is to:

```
result = result + str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(0);
```

which results in `result = "TT"`.

However, if I use the `+=` operator, e.g.:

```
result += str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(0);
```

I get `result = "168"`. Clearly character addition has taken place (ASCII code for 'T' is 84, 84*2 = 168).

I'm wondering what is actually going on in the first case using the `+=` operator. According to the [docs on assignment operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.26.2): `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))`. So I would expect the latter expression to output `"168"` just like using the `+=` operator did. But the following outputs `"TT"` correctly, and not `"168"`:

```
result = (String)(result + str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(0));
```

Have I just misunderstood the documentation? I also found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/693617) on SO that suggests that `str1 += str2` is equivalent to:

```
str1 = new StringBuilder().append(str1).append(str2).toString();
```

But evaluating the following:

```
result = new StringBuilder().append(str.charAt(0)).append(str.charAt(0)).toString();
```

Still results in `"TT"`, not `"168"`.

Sorry for the long post! I'm just curious at what actually is happening when using `charAt()` in combination with a String and `+=`, because the two "equivalents" I've found (if I've translated them from two to three terms correctly) does not produce the same result.

Comment: Is it sufficient to say "Don't do that"?  If not, look at [operator precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).

Comment: No, I can easily surpass the problem, but I wanted to learn from it too. Thanks for the link! I always forget to think of operator precedence.

Comment: It's kind of like the Spanish Inquisition.

Comment: Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you stated in your question `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))`. So the line

```
result += str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(0);
```

is equivalent to

```
result = (String) ((result) + (str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(0)));
```

(Note the parentheses around the char addition, they are important)

This will evaluate to

```
result = (String) (("") + ('T' + 'T'));
result = (String) (("") + (168));
result = (String) ("168");
result = "168";
```

whereas without parentheses you get

```
result = (String) ("" + 'T' + 'T');
result = (String) ("T" + 'T');
result = (String) ("TT");
result = "TT";
```

Answer (score 7):

```
result = result + str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(0);
```

`result` is a string, so the first `+` performs string concatenation, producing another string. The second `+`, by the same logic, will also perform string concatenation. This gives the desired result.

```
result += str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(0);
```

The right-hand side, `str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(0)`, is evaluated first. Now, you're adding two *characters*, which works like simple integer addition, adding the ASCII values. We then append this result (an `int` -- 84 in this case) to `result`, which is what you see.

```
char c = 'T';
System.out.println(c + c);
```

```
168
```

The underlying difference here is just the order in which things are evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

```
str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(0)
```

is evaluated as a whole before the assignment `+=` takes place.

`charAt` returns a `char`, on which addition is defined like on integers. Therefore, this is the same as :

```
result = result + (str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(0));
```