# Is += more efficient than concat?

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I've been reading code produced by other developers on my team, they seem to favor using `+=` for String concatenation, whereas I prefer using `.concat()` as it feels easier to read.

I'm trying to prepare an argument as to why using `.concat()` is better, and I'm wondering, is there any difference in efficiency between the two?

Which option "should" we be taking?

```
public class Stuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String hello = "hello ";
        hello += "world";
        System.out.println(hello);

        String helloConcat = "hello ".concat("world");
        System.out.println(helloConcat);
    }
}
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/java-string-concatenation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since String is immutable in java, when you do a `+`, `+=` or `concat(String)`, a new String is generated. The bigger the String gets the longer it takes - there is more to copy and more garbage is produced.

Today's java compilers optimizes your string concatenation to make it optimal, e.g.

```
System.out.println("x:"+x+" y:"+y);
```

Compiler generates it to:

```
System.out.println((new StringBuilder()).append("x:").append(x).append(" y:").append(y).toString());
```

My advice is to write code that's easier to maintain and read.

This link shows performance of [StringBuilder vs StringBuffer vs String.concat - done right](http://prafullaraut82.blogspot.in/2011/03/stringbuilder-vs-stringbuffer-vs.html)

Answer (score 10):

It shouldn't matter. Modern day Java compilers, JVMs and JITs will optimize your code in such a way that differences are likely to be minimal. You should strive to write code that's more readable and maintainable for you.

Comment: What would you say in case of mobile processors or where the resources are low, still these minimal wouldn't matter ??

Comment: @Pratik: those are cases when optimization does matter. OP's question didn't state that micro optimizations are needed. Of course you have to be careful what you're doing based on your environment. If you wanted to write an operating system, you wouldn't do it in a slow dynamic language if you want it to be very speedy.

Comment: I'm not sure what optimisation you are thinking of here.

Comment: @Tom: take a look at @aioobe's answer, for starters. And that's not the whole story since a JIT can optimize this code even more during runtime. What optimizations exactly? That would require peeking under the hood of both the JVM and the JIT, so you can do that if you want to. From my understanding both of them have been heavily optimized in last 15 years, so they probably do many tricks to speed up everything.

Comment: @aioobe's answer actually shows that very similar looking source code actually generates quite different object code - that is an argument against what you are saying. Really, there isn't much small bytecode->machine code optimisations can do with such different code.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @darioo and most other answers. Always put readability (and maintainability) first. (A modern JIT compiler should have no troubles with simple cases like these.)

Here is however the bytecode corresponding to your program. (Note that the `+=` approach results in a `StringBuilder` which is generally the preferred approach when constructing strings.)

```
// String hello = "hello";
0: ldc #2; //String hello 
2: astore_1

// hello += "world";
3: new #3; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
6: dup
7: invokespecial #4; //Method StringBuilder."<init>"
10: aload_1
11: invokevirtual #5; //Method StringBuilder.append
14: ldc #6; //String world
16: invokevirtual #5; //Method StringBuilder.append
19: invokevirtual #7; //Method StringBuilder.toString

// System.out.println(hello);
22: astore_1
23: getstatic #8; //Field System.out
26: aload_1
27: invokevirtual #9; //Method PrintStream.println

// String helloConcat = "hello ".concat("world");
30: ldc #2; //String hello 
32: ldc #6; //String world
34: invokevirtual #10; //Method String.concat
37: astore_2

// System.out.println(helloConcat);
38: getstatic #8; //Field System.out
41: aload_2
42: invokevirtual #9; //Method PrintStream.println

45: return
```

Answer (score 3):

In terms of readability, I think you are very wrong. `+` wins over `.concat()`. If you are using `+=`, you might want to think about `StringBuilder.append` keeping the same `StringBuilder` for the loop.

In terms of performance `concat` is better than `+`. so long as you only use one or perhaps two.

In the case of `concat`, you will end up creating a `String` object with a correctly sized `char[]`. It's about as optimal as you can get.

For `+` javac generates code that constructs a `StringBuilder` to do the appending and then converts to a `String`. From 1.5 you create:

- A `StringBuilder` (waste)
- Initial `char[]` for `StringBuilder` (waste)
- If resulting sequence is too long, a second bigger `char[]` (waste)
- The resulting `String`.
- The `String`'s `char[]`.

However, you rarely see `concat` used because it is more difficult to read. The performance is almost certainly going to be a drop in the ocean compared to what else is going on (hint: try the back of an envelope before optimising).

Answer (score 1):

You should do what you find is the shortest and clearest to you.

However, for your interest.

```
    String hello = "hello " + "world";
```

Is the fastest as the compile combined the two String into one.

This is fastest for two Strings as it avoids creating StringBuilder.

```
    String helloConcat = "hello ".concat(world);
```

However if you have more than two strings Using StringBuilder, either implicitly or explicitly is fastest.

In summary I would use + unless you have it in a loop in which case I might use StringBuilder explicitly to improve performance.

Comment: No modern Java compiler already uses `StringBuilder` under the hood and makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Concat is definitely a faster choice for two strings concatination, I don't know why javac internally uses

```
(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s1))).append(s2).toString()
```

instead of

```
s1.concat(s2)
```

for s1 += s2. See my answer to a similar question [concatenation operator (+) vs concat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755063/concatenation-operator-vs-concat/13739225#13739225)

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [artical](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/community/kabutz_qa.html) and made this test :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = generateString();
        String s2 = generateString();
        String s3 = generateString();
        String s4 = generateString();
        String s5 = generateString();
        String s6 = generateString();

        long e = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++){
        //StringBuilder > concat> plus >StringBuffer >plusEqual(">"means faster than)
            //concatPlus(s1 , s2 , s3 , s4 , s5 , s6);//4204ms
            //concatBuilder(s1 , s2 , s3 , s4 , s5 , s6);//2562ms
            //concatBuffer(s1 , s2 , s3 , s4 , s5 , s6);//4610ms
            //concatPlusEqual(s1 , s2 , s3 , s4 , s5 , s6);//9843ms
            //concatConcat(s1 , s2 , s3 , s4 , s5 , s6);//3036ms
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-e);           
    }

public static String concatPlusEqual(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4,
        String s5, String s6) {
       String result = "";
        result += s1;
        result += s2;
        result += s3;
        result += s4;
        result += s5;
        result += s6;
        return result;
}

    public static String concatConcat(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4,
            String s5, String s6) {
        String result = new String();
        result.concat(s1);
        result.concat(s2);
        result.concat(s3);
        result.concat(s4);
        result.concat(s5);
        result.concat(s6);
        return result;
    }


    public static String concatBuffer(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4,
            String s5, String s6) {
        return new StringBuffer(s1.length() + s2.length() + s3.length()
                + s4.length() + s5.length() + s6.length()).append(s1)
                .append(s2).append(s3).append(s4).append(s5).append(s6)
                .toString();
    }

    public static String concatBuilder(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4,
            String s5, String s6) {
        return new StringBuilder(s1.length() + s2.length() + s3.length()
                + s4.length() + s5.length() + s6.length()).append(s1)
                .append(s2).append(s3).append(s4).append(s5).append(s6)
                .toString();
    }

    public static String concatPlus(String s1,String s2,String s3,String s4,String s5,String s6) {
        return s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6;
    }
public static String generateString()
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int length = 10;
        String characters ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        char[] text = new char[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            text[i] = characters.charAt(rng.nextInt(characters.length()));
        }
        return new String(text);
    }
```

It looks like that **`StringBuilder`** is fastest and **`+=`** is slowest.
Just for reference!