# Complexity of finding all substrings of a string

Tags: java, complexity-theory

Here is a solution for finding all substrings of a string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    String subStr;
    for (int j = i; j < str.length(); j++) {
        subStr = str + str.charAt(j));
        System.out.println(subStr);
    }
}
```

All over the internet I read that the complexity of this code is O(n<sup>2</sup>).
However the + operation is an O(n) operation.
Thus in my opinion the complexity should be O(n<sup>3</sup>).

In case I am wrong, please correct my understanding.

Comment: Don't use `+`. Use `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a character to a string is a O(1) operation. You get O(n<sup>3</sup>) if you take into account also the time need to print the output with `println`.

Comment: "Adding a character to a string is a O(1) operation" : this is incorrect, since String is immutable, the concatenation happens in O(n) time. You could use a StringBuilder instead which would have O(1) time.

Comment: @VyshnavRameshThrissur are you sure? This depends on internal implementation. Tha java compiler might (and should) notice that the old value is discarded and hence make the character addition in place.

Comment: Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400508/string-concatenation-complexity-in-c-and-java  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323018/is-more-efficient-than-concat In short, during addition of two strings, a new StringBuilder is created. The first string chars are copied into this and the second string chars are appended to this. This is then converted to a string using toString() and returned.

Answer (score 1):

Finding all substrings of a string is O(n<sup>2</sup>) (by finding a substring I mean determining its begin and end indexes), it's easy to see because the total number of substrings is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

But printing all of them out is O(n<sup>3</sup>), simply because total number of characters to be printed is O(n<sup>3</sup>). In your code, `println` adds O(n) complexity (the `+` operator should have O(1) complexity if used/implemented properly).

Answer (score 1):

Finding all substrings from a string the naive way is indeed O(n^2). But the code in the question doesn't probably do that. Here is the corrected version.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        //Initialize with max length of the substring 
        StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder(str.length() - i);
        for (int j = i; j < str.length(); ++j) {
            prefix.append(str.charAt(j)); //this step is O(1).
            System.out.println(prefix); //this step is supposed to be O(1)
        }
    }

The total number of iterations is given by
Outer Loop  : Inner Loop
First time  : n
Second time : n - 1
Third Time  : n - 2
..
n - 2 time  : 2
n - 1 time  : 1 



So the total number of iterations is sum of iterations of outer loop plus sum of iterations of the inner loop.
n + (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n - 3 + n - 2 + n - 1 + n) is  = O(n^2)
```