# A "dry" principle case

Tags: c#, dry

there is a need to check the data entered by the user and display a notification on the screen in case of incorrect input. I used the following method, but it seems to me that it don't quite fit into the principle of "don't repeat yourself". Does anyone have any ideas for simplification?

```
int productid = 0;
string errorMessage = "Неправильный формат данных:\n",
       productName = "", productGroup = "", productType = "";
if (!int.TryParse(ProductIdTB.Text, out productId))
{
    errorMessage += "+ Номер продукта\n";
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductNameTB.Text))
{
    errorMessage += "+ Название продукта\n";
}
else
{
    productName = ProductNameTB.Text;
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductGroupTB.Text))
{
    errorMessage += "+ Группа продукта\n";
}
else
{
    productGroup = ProductGroupTB.Text;
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductType.Text))
{
    errorMessage += "+ Вид продукта";
}
else
{
    productType = ProductType.Text;
}
if (errorMessage.Split(' ').Length > 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show(errorMessage);
    return;
}
```

Comment: An opinion base question is not for stackoverflow.com, nonetheless  you are overwriting your variable with every if else condition, so if you have two errors you will be able to read just one at a time, maybe you can group your errors in some different way, or maybe throw an exception

Comment: You might want to consider removing all the `else` bits and simply populate the values only after the last condition, when you know there are no errors.

Comment: @DonMiguelSanchez No, OP is using `+=` thus appending to the errormessage variable not overwriting it ...

Comment: In the ASP.NET world we have model binders and validation attributes that perform all of the basic input validations so we don't have to.

Comment: Instead of splitting by `' '` you proably want to split by `'\n'` instead. And also the check with `> 1` won't work, as you already append `\n` to the header, thus the split will always give you two elements at minimum. I'd furthermore suggest not displaying such a big amount of data in a textbox. There are better means of validating and displaying errors in Windows Forms ...

Comment: @derpirscher, but it works...

Comment: What happens if there are no errors? Then `errormessage` is still `"Неправильный формат данных:\n"` ie it contains 2 spaces and `errormessage.Split(' ')` will result in an array of length `3`. Thus, your messagebox will *always*  be displayed

Comment: WPF already covers this through [data validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#data-validation), offering ways to specify validation rules on the form or object, trigger them automatically when a value changes, and display error indicators

Comment: @derpirscher i see, i should use 3, yep, just didn't notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine building a class that does the checks for you and collects all errors, either in a string or a list of strings.

```cs
class ErrorMessageBuilder
{
    string totalmessage = "";

    void AppendErrorIfEmpty(TextBox t, string textboxname)
    {
        if (t.Text.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            totalmessage += textboxname + " can't be empty" + Environment.NewLine;
        }    
    }

    void AppendErrorIfNotInt(TextBox t, string textboxname)
    {
         int value;
         if (!int.TryParse(t.Text, out value))
         {
             totalmessage += textboxname + " must be an integer number"  + Environment.NewLine;
         }
    }
}
```

This would reduce the code to

```cs
var emb = ErrorMessageBuilder();
emb.AppendErrorIfNotInt(ProductIdTB, "Product ID");
emb.AppendErrorIfEmpty(ProductNameTB, "Product Name");
...
```

---

Since this looks like WinForms development to me, you can also have a look at the [ErrorProvider class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider?view=windowsdesktop-8.0). Like with tooltips, it allows one error message per control. Perhaps that would be even more user-friendly.

Comment: Good idea, i'll use it

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much this is used, it might not scale out very well considering the immutability of strings. For every += you are creating a new string instance, the bigger the string the more memory and garbage...

Consider StringBuilder and it's Append/AppendFormat methods.

[+=/concat, string performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323132/7580507)

Comment: yep, but i use `+=` isn't it appending a string instead of creating a new one?

Comment: @programMUSTer: no, it doesn't it still creates a new string and gets rid of the old one. As long as you don't have kilobytes of strings, the normal approach with += is totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a windows forms UI, consider validating each textbox during the `TextBox.Leave` event when the user is done typing and the textbox loses focus. This will improve the DRY issue you posted about while also improving user experience.

The user will immediately know there is a problem, fix it, and continue.

I would use this in conjuction with building your own ErrorMessageHandler class, like in `@Thomas Weller`'s answer.

Something like this...

```
static class CustomError
{
    static string ErrorIfEmpty(TextBox t, string textboxname)
    {
        if (t.Text.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            return textboxname + " can't be empty";
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    static string ErrorIfNotInt(TextBox t, string textboxname)
    {
         if (!int.TryParse(t.Text, out value))
         {
             return textboxname + " must be an integer number";
         }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Each `TextBox.Leave` method could look like this.

```
private void ProductIdTB_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string errMsg = CustomError.ErrorIfNotInt(ProductIdTB,"Product ID");
    if (errMsg != "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(errMsg);
        ProductIdTB.Text = "";
        ....
    }            
}
```

In this way, the user is notified as soon as the mistake is made and they are ready to fix it and move on.