# Java - Convert integer to string

Tags: java, string, numbers, int

Given a number:

```
int number = 1234;
```

Which would be the "best" way to convert this to a string:

```
String stringNumber = "1234";
```

---

<sup>I have tried searching (googling) for an answer but no many seemed "trustworthy".</sup>

Comment: @lokesh I was taking a look at the valueOf implementation in the string class - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java.  toString will be called inside of String.valueOf. proxy in a sense.

Answer (score 1034, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

- `String.valueOf(number)` (my preference)
- `"" + number` (I don't know how the compiler handles it, perhaps it is as efficient as the above)
- `Integer.toString(number)`

Comment: I'll give it a go! thank you! BTW I had read about concatenation, but for some reason it feels like a hack more that a solution (not a  technical assessment) thanks!!

Comment: @Trufa - I would use valueOf() out of these 3.

Comment: I checked the source code (1.6.0.24 Sun) and the first and third options are basically identical. String.valueOf(int) delegates to Integer.toString(int) for radixes of 10.

Comment: @stoupa - yes, but you can use `String.valueOf(..)` with any argument.

Comment: Are these three solutions "compiled" to one thing ? Or one of those is preferable ?

Comment: they are practically the same (the last one invokes the first one, and the 2nd one is compiled to the first one). I prefer the 1st one

Comment: @Bozho Your last comment is BACKWARDS. Actually, the first way invokes the last. (See String source in JDK at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java?av=f .)

Comment: Notably, also, the first will not validate it is actually receiving an int versus some other primitive/type since the method is overloaded in String. From a type checking perspective, "Integer.toString()" is much better.

Comment: StringBuilder is also an option like http://javadevnotes.com/java-integer-to-string-examples

Comment: int oopsPitfall = 0700; String.valueOf(oopsPitfall);

Comment: `"" + number` uses `StringBuilder` as of JDK 7, `StringBuilder` uses `Integer.getChars` to convert the `int` into a `String`. It's not a good approach to use unless your already using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @jba If you add a zero before an integer, it is taken as an octal nonetheless. So what String.valueof() gives is actually right and is not a pitfall.

Comment: Number 2 has a lot of extra overhead (it's equivalent to `new StringBuilder().append("").append(number).toString()`)

Comment: I prefer option 3. It seems to be the most efficient approach, there's the compile time integer check and also if I want to convert "Integer to String", it sounds good to call "Integer.toString".

Comment: ```"" + number``` actually uses StringBuilder

Answer (score 65):

Integer class has static method toString() - you can use it:

```
int i = 1234;
String str = Integer.toString(i);
```

> Returns a String object representing the specified integer. The argument is converted to signed decimal representation and returned as a string, exactly as if the argument and radix 10 were given as arguments to the toString(int, int) method.

Answer (score 53):

Always use either `String.valueOf(number)` or `Integer.toString(number)`.

Using "" + number is an overhead and does the following:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("");
sb.append(number);
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: The bytecode compiler can't optimize that away? I would expect the optimizer to remove the sb.append(""). But I don't know much about compiler optimization in Java.

Comment: It can. Java 11 compiler produces an invocation of `makeConcatWithConstants`. Some older releases used StringBuffer maybe.

Answer (score 46):

This will do. Pretty trustworthy. : )

```
    ""+number;
```

Just to clarify, this works and acceptable to use unless you are looking for micro optimization.

Comment: Thank you very much, this actually woks I don't like it though (nothing technical about my dislike) I just "feel" like it is a hack, not a real solution (probably not true).

Comment: Your answer has a lot of extra overhead (it's equivalent to new StringBuilder().append("").append(number).toString())

Comment: @SolomonUcko may I know your source of this information? I would like to add to the answer if it is correct.

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47626/5445670

Answer (score 22):

The way I know how to convert an integer into a string is by using the following code:

```
Integer.toString(int);
```

and

```
String.valueOf(int);
```

If you had an integer i, and a string s, then the following would apply:

```
int i;
String s = Integer.toString(i); or
String s = String.valueOf(i);
```

If you wanted to convert a string "s" into an integer "i", then the following would work:

```
i = Integer.valueOf(s).intValue();
```

Comment: which differences: `Integer.toString(i)` vs `String.valueOf(i)` ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the method which i used to convert the integer to string.Correct me if i did wrong.

```
/**
 * @param a
 * @return
 */
private String convertToString(int a) {

    int c;
    char m;
    StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
    // convert the String to int
    while (a > 0) {
        c = a % 10;
        a = a / 10;
        m = (char) ('0' + c);
        ans.append(m);
    }
    return ans.reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: (1) Doesn't work with negatives [are you a C developer who loves unsigned int?] (2) Relies on truncation [we all know what assume means ...] (3) overly verbose (4) WHY?!

Comment: Apart from problems described by @ingyhere , it also doesn't work for leading zeroes. 0123 as input becomes 83

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to do any of this. You're attempting to shave off each digit from the integer *backwards*, convert each digit to a character manually, append each digit *one at a time* to the string builder, before reversing the whole thing to get the original ordering back. **Why?** A `StringBuilder` can just **accept the whole integer in one call to append!** And it works across all the special cases your code fails for. You can replace this entire thing with `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.append(intValue); return sb.toString();`