# Java - How do you make a jButton# index take the value of an int variable?

Tags: java, loops, button, parameters, jbutton

I need to perform actions on hundreds of buttons. I'm looking for a way to use a loop for the jButton index, instead of writing hundreds of lines of code just to change the color of multiple buttons.
I want something like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
    jButton("i").setForeground(Color.red)
}
```

So for example for n=18, the command executed is:

```
jButton18.setForeground(Color.red)...
```

Which obviously does not work, but there has to be a simpler way than to write a line for each button!

Comment: What is `jButton("i")`? Is it all buttons with the title `i`?

Comment: Are the JButtons in a List or array?

Comment: `jButton("i")` is sure invalid. Check your code syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to instantiate hundreds of buttons what you'll want is to have them in an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). That would probably look something like this:
`JButton[] array = new JButton[100]`.

You can then loop through the array using your for loop and change the colour of each button like this: 
`array[i].setForground(Color.red))`.

You can initialize the buttons in a similar way by setting the values of each index like this: `array[i] = JButton("textHere")`.

If you want to number them all differently there's a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071040/java-convert-integer-to-string) on how to convert numbers to strings so you can do it inside your loop.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Put all your `JButton` instances in a `List` once you create them, and then you can just iterate over them:

```
for (JButton jButton : myJButtons) {
    jButton.setForeground(Color.red))
}
```