# String double calculation with java

Tags: java, string, numbers

Any best way to calculate numbers in string format ?

for example have

```
String n1 = 0.000112
String n2 = 0.000222
```

n1 + n2 - I can convert string to double make calculation. But after that I should convert this in string like this

```
n1 + n2 = string like this "0.000334"
```

Any best way how to do it with java ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071040/java-convert-integer-to-string?rq=1

Comment: You have to use `BigDecimal` rather than `double`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String n1 = "0.000112";
    String n2 = "0.000222";

    System.err.println( new BigDecimal( n1).add( new BigDecimal( n2)).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.valueOf(double)` and `Double.parseDouble(String)`:

```
String result = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("0.01") + Double.parseDouble("0.02"));
```

Another option would be this (I'll leave out the parsing):

```
String s = "" + doubleValue;
```

The list of possible conversions from `double` to String is pretty endless.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example, I am not sure if you care about the decimal precision. So for example, if I was to maintain 10 decimal places of accuracy I would try the following.

```
String n1 = "0.000112";
String n2 = "0.000222";

BigDecimal n1Big = new BigDecimal(n1).setScale(10,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
BigDecimal result = n1Big.add(new BigDecimal(n2));

String ans = result.toString();

System.out.println(ans);
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A good approach with `BigDecimal` has been showed in other answers. I will describe how you can do it as per your strategy in the question:

> Convert string to double make calculation

- Convert `String` to `Double`

  ```
  Double nd1 = Double.parseDouble(n1);
  Double nd2 = Double.parseDouble(n2);
  ```
- Add it

  ```
  Double sum = nd1 + nd2;
  ```

> But after that I should convert this in string

- Then convert it back to `String`. Here you need to specify the format with precision.

  ```
  String s = new DecimalFormat("#.######").format(sum);
  System.out.println(s);
  ```

Output:
`0.000334`