# How to convert int to string (Android)

Tags: java, android

How to convert int to string in `params.put("kodepospelanggan", kodepospelanggan);` where `kodepospelanggan` is an int?

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    // Posting parameters to register
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("namaperusahaan", namaperusahaan);
    params.put("jenisusaha", jenisusaha);
    params.put("namapelanggan", namapelanggan);
    params.put("alamatpelanggan",alamatpelanggan );
    params.put("kelurahanpelanggan", kelurahanpelanggan);
    params.put("kecamatanpelanggan", kecamatanpelanggan);
    params.put("kotapelanggan", kotapelanggan);
    params.put("kodepospelanggan", kodepospelanggan); // how to convert this integer to String ?

    return params;
}
```

Comment: This looks like java not javascript. In java you can use `String.valueOf(intVariable)` or `Integer.toString(intVariable)`.

Comment: Why are you tagging `javascript` for this question?

Comment: kodepospelanggan is an integer? if so, please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071040/java-convert-integer-to-string

Comment: thanks you. sorry it's suppose to be java

Answer (score 3):

If it were a JavaScript, you would use [`Number.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method:

```
> a = 123
123
> a.toString()
'123'
```

Since it's Java, use [`Integer.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int)):

```
int a = 123;
String s = Integer.toString(a);
```