# What is the Ideal Way to Convert an Integer to a String in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy

In plain old Java, there are many ways to convert an integer to a string, such that `5` becomes `"5"`. The answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071040/java-convert-integer-to-string) have several good suggestions, `String.valueOf(number)` being my favorite.

My question is does Groovy provide a different/better way to do this? Or is the Java method still the way to go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does `toString()` work for you? It looks pretty descriptive to me, and it beats out `''+5` performance-wise.

```
Integer x = 5;
System.out.println(x.toString());
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_tostring.htm

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your use case, you can do this very simply with a GString:

```
String str = "$number"
```