# How to convert 2d Integer array into 2d String array?

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I have a two dimensional Integer array and I need to convert it into a two dimensional String array.

```
private Integer[][] microboardArray = new Integer[9][9];
```

Then I have "get" method from interface which must be implemented.

```
@Override
public String[][] getBoard() {

}
```

Thank you for your help :).

Comment: Did you try to implement it by yourself? What problems did you face with? From my point of view, you'll need just two loops

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Convert integer to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071040/java-convert-integer-to-string)

Comment: @Kirill can you tell me which loops do I need? I have no clue.

Comment: @MapeSVK please examine the answer from Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String[][] getBoard() {
    String[][] board = new String[9][9];

    for(int i=0 ; i<9;i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<9; j++){
            board[i][j] = microboardArray[i][j].toString();
        }
    }
    return board;
    }
```