# How to return a String after Integer/String manipulation?

Tags: java, string, return

I just want to return a string from this code. How can I fix this??

```
String foo(String s) {
    return (12+Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,2))).toString()+s.substring(2,8);
}
```

Comment: What language? What is that you're getting instead of what you expected?

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work. What result are you getting?

Comment: @emsimpson92 based on lower camel case I'd guess Java.

Comment: Language is java

Comment: @emsimpson92 i m getting integer cant be dereferenced error

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071040/java-convert-integer-to-string

Comment: You are trying to do too many things in one line of code. You should break this up and assign each intermediate value to its own variable. This will help you more easily find the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to return the integer sum as a string?

In java, using the `+` operator on strings will append the strings rather than perform math addition.

If I understand your question correctly, you need to do something like this:

```
String foo(String s) {
    return (12+Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,2))+Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2,8)).toString());
}
```

This will add 12 + someInt + someOtherInt and then return the result as a String.

Answer (score 0):

Change to
return String.valueOf(12+Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,2)) + s.substring(2,8);