# How to print both bool and double in same line?

Tags: java

I am working on this very simple java problem which requires to print both the objects money and isTrue without skipping a line.

I have tried casting both objects to string but doesn't work. I know I could have two print statements but they would print on 2 differents lines. I need both to print as 9999.99false

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double money = 9999.99;
    boolean isTrue = false;
    System.out.println(money + isTrue);
  }
}
```

The output expected is 9999.99false

Thanks!

Comment: `System.out.println("" + money + isTrue);` but I would prefer `System.out.printf("%.2f%b%n", money, isTrue);`

Comment: `System.out.print(money); System.out.println(isTrue);`

Comment: Are you aware of `System.out.print`, which is like `println` but without starting a new line?

Comment: If you used print twice instead of println, they'd be on the same line

Comment: `I have tried casting both objects to string but doesn't work.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071040/java-convert-integer-to-string/5071064 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Boolean.html

Comment: How are you learning Java? This should be covered in any basic tutorial.

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening right now is the compiler is seeing that you are trying to add a `double` and a `boolean` together using the `+` operator, which it does not know how to do. One option is to use the below code:

```
System.out.println("" + money + isTrue);
```

The first String literal tells the compiler to add a `String` and a `double`, which the compiler can do successfully by implicitly converting the `double` to a `String`. The same thing happens with the `boolean`.

Since `String` is a class, and `double` and `boolean` are primitive types, casting does not work between the two like it would in C# (see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting) for more information on that).

This produces your expected output when run:

```
9999.99false
```