# Printing 2 different variables in the same line Java VM

Tags: java

I am new to java and i have 2 different Variables one is a double and one is a boolean. I am having difficulty printing them into the same line, this is my code.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean isTrue;
    isTrue = false;
        double money;
        money = 99999.99;
System.out.println(isTrue, double);
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot if you answer

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. I think you need to replace `double` with `money` in the last line, i.e. `System.out.println(isTrue, double);` Is that your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print both bool and double in same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57846940/how-to-print-both-bool-and-double-in-same-line)

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this and if you visited the javadocs you would see that there is also `System.out.print` which does not do a line feed, so you could use that as

```
System.out.print(isTrue);
System.out.println(money);
```

Or you could use `System.out.printf`, or convert values into a `String` first

Comment: Did you try to run the code from the question? If you did, did it work for you as written in the question?

Comment: @abra Does the code in the question does not even compile? How can I run it?  I have answered the question *Printing 2 different variables in the same line Java VM*

Comment: A quote from the question: _I am having difficulty printing them into the same line_ Do you know what that difficulty is? If you don't then how can you claim to have answered the question?

Answer (score 0):

There are few methods to do this, one is mentioned in the above answer and the other is below, that you can do this with a  professional approach by using `printf`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean isTrue;
            isTrue = false;
            double money;
            money = 99999.99;
            System.out.printf("%b%.2f%n", isTrue, money);
        }
```

Comment: I have tried putting it in the compiler and it puts out a bug that's like                                 exit status 1
Main.java:7: error: no suitable method found for println(double,boolean)
System.out.println(money, isTrue);
          ^
    method PrintStream.println() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method PrintStream.println(boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method PrintStream.println(char) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

1 error