# Is converting "Integer to String" by appending it to double quotes like 'return ("" + 2)' costly operation? If yes, what is alternative?

Tags: java, string, parseint

I have integer status response from a REST API. I need to return string, so I use it like

```
return "" + statusCode
```

Is it fine way to do that or is it costly? Or should I use `String.valueOf()` or is there another alternative?

Comment: "if consider space/time thing" what does that even means?

Comment: In the context of a network request, I think it's almost *certain* that this will be noise... but `String.valueOf(statusCode)` is the *cleanest* way to do it, IMO, because it says what you're trying to do: obtain the string representation of a value. You're not logically trying to perform any string concatenation.

Comment: There are lots of ways of converting an integer to a string, and no shared meaning for the word "costly". Benchmark and decide which option works best for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071040/java-convert-integer-to-string

Comment: as Jon [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72308775/is-converting-integer-to-string-by-appending-it-to-double-quotes-like-return#comment127745380_72308775), using `valueOf()` or, as I  prefer (for *reading*), `Integer.toString(statusCode)` is better to communicate what you want to accomplish. Concatenation is probably a little bit more *expensive* unless the compiler is smart enough to eliminate it (OPenJDK's does NOT), but I doubt the difference will be relevant compared to network performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need - if you decompile the class file, you'll see that the compiler does this for you anyway. I think this makes the code very readable, however you might want to ask yourself why are you doing this anyway... if you are confident that returning a number as a string from a method is correct, this is a good way to do it, IMO.