# Best practices/performance: mixing StringBuilder.append with String.concat

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, string-concatenation

I'm trying to understand what the best practice is and why for concatenating string literals and variables for different cases. For instance, if I have code like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("AAAAAAAAAAAAA")
    .append(B_String).append("CCCCCCCCCCC").append(D_String)
    .append("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE")
    .append("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
```

Is this the way to do it? From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/java-string-concatenation), I noticed that the `+` operator on Strings creates a new instance of StringBuilder, concatenates the operands, and returns a String conversion, which seems like a lot more work than just calling `.append()`; so if that's true, then that is out of the question. But what about `String.concat()`? Is it proper to use `.append()` for every concatenation? Or just for variables, and literals are okay to append with `.concat()`?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("AAAAAAAAAAAAA")
    .append(B_String.concat("CCCCCCCCCCC")).append(D_String
    .concat("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE")
    .concat("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"));
```

What are the general rules for best practices and performance for going about these situations? Is my assumption correct on `+` and it should really just not be used?

Comment: I think basically you've got it. Opinions differ as to whether String + "really should just not be used". The point is that you understand the consequences

Answer (score 189, accepted):

## `+` operator

```
String s = s1 + s2
```

Behind the scenes this is translated to:

```
String s = new StringBuilder(s1).append(s2).toString();
```

Imagine how much extra work it adds if you have `s1 + s2` here:

```
stringBuilder.append(s1 + s2)
```

instead of:

```
stringBuilder.append(s1).append(s2)
```

### Multiple strings with `+`

Worth to note that:

```
String s = s1 + s2 + s3 + ... +sN
```

is translated to:

```
String s = new StringBuilder(s1).append(s2).append(s3)...apend(sN).toString();
```

## `concat()`

```
String s = s1.concat(s2);
```

`String` creates `char[]` array that can fit both `s1` and `s2`. Copies `s1` and `s2` contents to this new array. Actually requires less work then `+` operator.

## `StringBuilder.append()`

Maintains an internal `char[]` array that grows when needed. No extra `char[]` is created if the internal one is sufficiently big.

```
stringBuilder.append(s1.concat(s2))
```

is also performing poorly because `s1.concat(s2)` creates an extra `char[]` array and copies `s1` and `s2` to it just to copy that new array contents to internal `StringBuilder` `char[]`.

That being said you should use `append()` all the time and append raw strings (your first code snippet is correct).

Comment: Thanks for your help, and the in-depth explanation; that's what I really needed.

Comment: Although newer versions of the compiler automatically optimize the + operator to a string builder it isn't necessarily a good thing to assume it will as older versions don't.  There is a very important topic that is being ignored in this whole discussion which is actually one of the main purposes for StringBuilder which is the string pool. Using a string builder keeps everything as a char[] and doesn't create an intermediate String like the + operator did before compiler optimizations(used to just do a concat).  Using concat creates an intermediate String object which is cached but not used.

Comment: So if I'm doing a *one-time statement* (not multiple statements accross a method) concatenation on several different strings. It would be okay to use `+` on the String objects instead of creating a `StringBuilder` for this one time concatenation, since it will basically do the same thing?

Comment: And if I want to concat only a character, is it better to use .append('\n') instead of .append("\n")? As a character is a primitive type, and a String is an Object?

Comment: _Effective Java 2-nd edition_: __Using the string concatenation operator repeatedly to concatenate n strings requires time quadratic in n.__ So is it still relevant?

Comment: @gkiko: Well, I think that you can safely ignore it if you're coding for modern compilers. The string concatenation optimization is mentioned in the Java Language Specification of 1.6 ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/expressions.html#15.18.1.2 ), although I'm not sure since when it was actually implemented in the Sun/Oracle VM. If it REALLY matters to you, have a look at the generated bytecode before doing String +, but I think it's the easiest and most readable way (and I've been routinely doing StringBuilder.append for YEARS :).

Answer (score 16):

The compilier optimize the + concatenation.

So

```
int a = 1;
String s = "Hello " + a;
```

is transformed into

`new StringBuilder().append("Hello ").append(1).toString();`

There an excellent topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java) explaining why you should use the + operator.

Comment: The compiler would actually optimize that into `String s = "Hello World";` since you use literals.

Comment: @ColinD : +1. Just modified my snippet.

Comment: "Hello " will be in constructor of StringBuilder

Answer (score 3):

Optimization is done automatically by the compiler.

The Java2 compiler will automatically convert the following:

```
String s = s1 + s2;
```

to

```
String s = (new StringBuffer()).append(s1).append(s2).toString();
```

Taken straight from the [Java Best Practices](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97688_16/generic.903/bp/java.htm#1007796) on Oracles website.

Answer (score 2):

You should always use `append`.

`concat` create a new String so it's pretty like `+` I think.

If you `concat` or use `+` with 2 final String the JVM can make optimisation so it's the same as doing append in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you concat exactly two Strings use String.concat (creates a new String by creating a new char-array that fits both Strings and copys both Strings' char arrays into it).

If you concat multiple (more than two) Strings in one line, use + or StringBuilder.append, it doesn't matter, since the compiler converts + to StringBuilder.append. This is good for multiple Strings because it maintains one char array that grows as needed.

If you concat multiple Strings over multiple lines create one StringBuilder and use the append-method. In the end when you are done appending Strings to the StringBuilder use it's .toString()-method to create a String out of it.
For concatting in multiple lines this is faster than the second method, since the second method would create a new StringBuilder on each line, append the Strings and then cast back to String, while the third method only uses one StringBuilder for the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the `Strings.format()`, simple easy to read one-line [string formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

```
String b = "B value";
String d = "D value";
String fullString = String.format("A %s C %s E F", b, d);
// Output: A B value C D value E F
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` operator is best practice, it is also simple and readable.

> The Java language provides special support for the string
>   concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to
>   strings. String concatenation is implemented through the
>   StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method.

Offical document: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

in byte code level there is not different and we are not compromising effeciancy there. In case of executing byte code level, it must go through non-inline operator overloading method for + by calling append. then in assembly language level (Java is written in C and C produces assemblies similar to assembly, there will be extra register call to store + method call in the stack and there will additional push. (in reality, cross-compiler might optimise + operator call, in that case making it no difference with efficiancy.)

It is a good practice to have one way to increase the readability. :)

Answer (score 0):

All answers are pretty good and explanatory. But I felt exploration around other string concatenation techniques would also help like - Guava Joiner, Streams, String.format etc.

For complete details over performance of each concatenation technique [java-string-concatenation-which-way-is-best](https://redfin.engineering/java-string-concatenation-which-way-is-best-8f590a7d22a8).

In Brief, concatenation performance varies with no. of strings to concatenate. For example - to concatenate 1-10 strings, these techniques works best - StringBuilder, StringBuffer and Plus Operator.
And to concatenate 100s of strings - Guava Joiner, apache's stringsUtils library also works great.

Please go through the above blog. It really explains performance efficiency very well.

Thanks.