# String concatenate Jmeter + BeanShell

Tags: string, jmeter, string-concatenation, beanshell

I am trying to concatenate string in JMeter BeanShell PostProcessor but somehow its not working, it seems like the way java handles multiple line string doesn't work here:

```
String poXML="<S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><S:Header/><S:Body><ns7:NewPORequest " +    "xmlns:ns2=\"http://services.portal.com/pro/common\" xmlns:ns5=\"http://services.portal.com/pro/po\" + "xmlns:ns7=\"http://services.portal.com/proc/ws\">" +
"<ns7:tracingLevel>OFF</ns7:tracingLevel><ns7:userId>TestUtil</ns7:userId><ns7:applicationId>RF</ns7:applicationId>" +
"<ns7:userType>Buyer</ns7:userType><ns5:PurchaseOrder><ns5:poExternalId>XXX-930220</ns5:poExternalId>" +
"<ns5:repairOrderNumber>vars.get("OrderNumber")</ns5:repairOrderNumber>";
```

I can concatenate simple one line but when it comes to multiple line its not working.
Single line:

```
print("PO XML="+"<ns5:repairOrderNumber>"+vars.get("OrderNumber")+"</ns5:repairOrderNumber>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing special but:

1. missing closing quotes near `...xmlns:ns5=\"http://services.portal.com/pro/po\" + "xmlns...` - should be `...xmlns:ns5=\"http://services.portal.com/pro/po\"" + "xmlns...`;
2. missing escape character in `repairOrderNumber>vars.get("OrderNumber")</ns5:` - use `>vars.get(\"OrderNumber\")<` if you want to have string itself in result (i.e. `vars.get("OrderNumber")`) or concatenate separately `+ vars.get("OrderNumber") +` to resolve expression to variable's value (as in your second sample).

   ```
   String poXML="<S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><S:Header/><S:Body><ns7:NewPORequest"+" xmlns:ns2=\"http://services.portal.com/pro/common\""+" xmlns:ns5=\"http://services.portal.com/pro/po\""+" xmlns:ns7=\"http://services.portal.com/proc/ws\">"+"<ns7:tracingLevel>OFF</ns7:tracingLevel><ns7:userId>TestUtil</ns7:userId><ns7:applicationId>RF</ns7:applicationId>"+"<ns7:userType>Buyer</ns7:userType><ns5:PurchaseOrder><ns5:poExternalId>XXX-930220</ns5:poExternalId>"+"<ns5:repairOrderNumber>"+vars.get("OrderNumber")+"</ns5:repairOrderNumber>";
   ```

As well looks like [usage of StringBuilder.append() is a bit better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078912/java-string-concatenation-best-practices-performance).