# How is + implemented in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java String concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/java-string-concatenation)

Sources tell us that `concat` is implemented as follows:

```
   public String concat(String str) {
        int otherLen = str.length();
        if (otherLen == 0) {
            return this;
        }
        int len = value.length;
        char buf[] = Arrays.copyOf(value, len + otherLen);
        str.getChars(buf, len);
        return new String(buf, true);
    }
```

Does `+` implementation differ when it comes to Strings? How? Is there a performance difference between `+` and `concat`. When should one be chosen over another?

Comment: Before someone closes this, note, that the question is not whether `+` is the same as `concat`, but rather deals with specific `+` implementation. Thank you

Comment: Which, as the linked answer states, is done with `StringBuilder` and it's `append` method. It also address your performance consideration questions.

Comment: Actually, I'm of the opinion that the _question_ has to be a duplicate to be closed-as-dupe. The fact that it may be answered in a totally unrelated question in no way makes the _question_ a dupe. Note that I'm not saying this _isn't_ a dupe question, just that the "answered elsewhere" reasoning for closing as a dupe is flawed - it should be "asked elsewhere".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a test I just made:

I created a class with those 3 instructions:

```
    String s1 = "foo";
    String s2 = "bar";
    String s3 = s1 + s2;
```

Then I took the generated .class file and I decompiled using JAD decompiler. 
This is how the code show up in the regenerated source:

```
    String s = "foo";
    String s1 = "bar";
    String s2 = (new StringBuilder()).append(s).append(s1).toString();
```

So: this is the difference between + and concat.

I guess concat() is always better than StringBuilder, because it requires less objects to be created. You may chose StringBuilder if you want to append string repeatedly in a loop; in this case concat may create a new String each time, while StringBuilder may just expand the internal buffer. But, if StringBuilder is best in this last scenario, we can say that still concat() is better than +, in loops.

Comment: +1 for a clever approach. but should probably note that this is implementation dependent, there is nothing in the Java spec AFAIK to stop + being implemented with concat when there are two String inputs

Comment: [JLS 15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) specifically says it's implementation-dependent. But a StringBuilder will quickly become better than `concat()` because `concat()` needs to copy all of the previous chars, meaning that if you're concatting 5 strings, the first one will have its chars copied 4 times (the second one 3 times, etc). With StringBuilder, there's only one copy per String.