# Optimize String += or Concat?

Tags: java, android

I am writing a file with possibly 1000 data points.  I have classes for all of these and am currently writing all of the data at the end (the datapoints are taken at 1s intervals).  What I am currently doing is written below, and it's very slow.  Would I be better off changing how I am writing the string/bytes to the file? Or would I be better off writing this information to some file pointer as the application is running?

Btw, all of the things such as `getAccuracy()` and such are floats/ints (so it has to convert those also).

```
fileStr = "";
        fileStr += "timestamp,Accuracy,Altitude,Latitude,Longitude,GPSSatelliteEntries\r\n";
        for (Iterator<Entry> i = entries.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Entry item = i.next();
            long ts = item.getTs();
            DataEntry d = item.getD();
            List<GPSSatelliteEntry> satellites = item.getG();

            // write stuff
            fileStr += ts + ",";
            fileStr += d.getAccuracy() + "," + d.getAltitude() + "," + d.getLatittude() + "," + d.getLongitude() + ",";
            fileStr += "[";
            boolean entered = false;
            for (Iterator<GPSSatelliteEntry> j = satellites.iterator(); j.hasNext(); ) {
                GPSSatelliteEntry item2 = j.next();
                entered = true;
                fileStr += "(" + item2.getAzimuth() + "," + item2.getElevation() + "," + item2.getPrn() + "," + item2.getSnr() + "),";
            }
            // chop off extra ,
            if (entered)
                fileStr = fileStr.substring(0, fileStr.length() - 1);
            fileStr += "]";
            fileStr += "\r\n";
        }
```

Comment: StringBuilder/Buffer woot woot!

Comment: For ints and floats (or Integer and Float) I would recommend using String.valueOf()

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/java-string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator?rq=1

Comment: @Aquillo So you wouldn't recommend using `Float.toString()` and `Integer.toString()`?

Comment: @MasterGberry If they are primitives, use `toString()`, otherwise use `String.valueOf()`

Comment: @MasterGberry, In fact it doesn't matter, the toString() function is the same as the String.valueOf() function. The advantage of `String.valueOf()` is that it doesn't matter if it's an int or a float (more or less readability).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everytime you have hard work with Strings, use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) to achieve better performance .

Don't forget that `String` is [**immutable**](http://javarevisited.blogspot.sk/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html), and each time you modify `String` new instance will be created and it costs performance.

Comment: What exactly is "hard work"? If String is immutable, then how can it be modified? And how does creating a new `String" "costs performance"?

Comment: Any work is hard, I suggest doing as little of it as possible.  Creating a new string "costs performance" because there are operations related to memory allocation, pointers, and other things that happen when you create one.  Using something like a StringBuilder will allow you to save this overhead because you are using a single object.  When applied over a large data set you can see significant differences in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably   [`string buffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

> A thread-safe, mutable sequence of characters. A string buffer is like a String, but can be modified.

or go for [`string builder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder stuff = new StringBuilder();
stuff.append("PUT YOUR STRINGS HERE");
stuff.append("PUT YOUR STRINGS HERE");
```

Then you can use 'stuff' to print the strings.
Put it in a loop and iterate over a large number with a timer to see the advantages, it's pretty interesting.

Comment: Or chaining ofcourse, which in this case might just be useful.

Comment: Chaining is an excellent suggestion here.  Chaining rather than using string concatenation within each call to append will save cycles.