# How to extract string between a particular string in java. Using itext adding extracted string to make it as bold

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching, itext, string-matching

I am finding the string in between **123** and **321** and making it as bold.

For that I used the Pattern to get the string before **123**, text between **123** and **321** and text after **321**.

> Could anyone please help me to get all the strings between **123** and **321**.

Below code only helps me to get the first occurrence of **123** and **321**.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*?(123)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(meredithEditorialSectionSegment);
while (m.find()) {
  String desc = m.group();
  String segDesc = (desc.substring(0, desc.length() - 3));
  segmentDesc.add(new Chunk(segDesc, sectionDescriptionFont));
}
descBold =  meredithEditorialSectionSegment.substring(meredithEditorialSectionSegment.indexOf("123") + 3);
descBold = descBold.substring(0, descBold.indexOf("321"));
segmentDesc.add(new Chunk(descBold, sectionDescriptionBoldFont));

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=321).*").matcher(meredithEditorialSectionSegment);
matcher.find();
segmentDesc.add(new Chunk(matcher.group(), sectionDescriptionFont));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
String str = "Could anyone please help me to get all the"+
             " strings between 123 and 321.\nMaybe 123 and another 321."+
             " Also,123 this must be matched.321\nhey!"+
             " 312 And 123 this must NOT be matched. ";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?123)(.*?)(321.*?)",Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();

        int last=0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.print(matcher.group(1)+"["+matcher.group(2)+"]"+matcher.group(3));
            last=matcher.end(3);
        }
        //the rest of the string
        System.out.println(str.substring(last));
```

Notes:

- I've added the *`DOTALL`* flag, (for avoiding newlines issues)
- In your case, you only have to adapt the `group(2)` string

---

Output:

```
Could anyone please help me to get all the strings between 123[ and ]321.
Maybe 123[ and another ]321. Also,123[ this must be matched.]321
hey! 312 And 123 this must NOT be matched.
```

Comment: Note that if synchronisation isn't an issue, you should probably use a `StringBuilder` instead. From the StringBuffer javadoc: `As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, StringBuilder. The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.`

Comment: @ABoschman that's true, but this was only an example. If you read again the question, there's no string concatenation in it. Anyway,you're right

Comment: You're right, it's not really relevant to the question, but we might as well set the right example. :)

Comment: @ABoschman Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator . I didn't knew that