# Which one to use- String or StringBuffer in concatenation

Tags: java, string, object, stringbuffer

I saw the java code in my project which constructs a file name from various parameters.The java code is like this

```
String file = null;
String fileDirSeperator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
String pwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
file = pwd + fileDirSeperator + "properties" + fileDirSeperator + folder_name + file_name;
```

I want to know if I should you `StringBuffer` instead of `String`. I know that appending anything to String will create new object so I think I should you `StringBuffer`.

May I know your suggestion?

Also,

```
 file = pwd + fileDirSeperator + "properties" + fileDirSeperator + folder_name + file_name;
```

in the above file name construction, will 6 objects be created(one for each variable)?

Comment: If you're concatenating only 6 Strings, I wouldn't care that much about performance. Use `+` and don't over-complicate it.

Comment: @BobbyDigital not for this case. The generated bytecode will already use `StringBuilder` for you.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I saw that!

Comment: Really the only time you'll have to be concerned about string concatenation with `+` is in loops/recursive calls/etc., especially if you save the result into a temp variable. For one-off things like this, you'll end up writing the same code as what the compiler will generate anyways.

Answer (score 6):

This is irrelevant. Unless you're doing this in a loop you run thousands of times, the performance doesn't matter. The `String` concatenation syntax would be the most straight forward then.

When performance is an issue with concatenation, use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of the options you mentioned.

Of course with such a small use case, it doesn't really matter

Comment: -1: In this case, the compiler will use `StringBuilder` for you. Check the generated bytecode. Use `StringBuilder` only when concatenating through a loop, when the compiler cannot do any code optimization.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Could you point to a reference?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Seriously, no kidding that it's not hard to replicate!!! I was asking if you have any authorative links to point to that explain that choice. Thanks for the -1 by the way :)

Comment: It takes less than 5 minutes to replicate. Anyway, here's a link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/47605/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I would say that it takes less than 2 to replicate, but as I explained, that was not my question. Thanks for the link :). And by the way, not every one is in the habbit of reading bytecode or decompiling class files for such simple use cases :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Good for you! Many people would rather indulge in other development related things and only get down to the bytecode-decompiling level when that's absolutely needed. Personally I would much rather try out what is new in Spring 4.0.5 than go through unsexy bytecode

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Spring was just an example! There is so much other stuff out there as I am sure you know, that in my opinion is so much more interesting that bytecode

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I can't agree with you more, that some subtle problems can perhaps only be spotted at the bytecode level. I am all for bytecode reading, but what I am saying is that I personally will not indulge in it's pleasures unless I really need to or unless I am done checking out all the other cool stuff around (which will never happen :))

Answer (score 0):

Having benchmarked this across tens of thousands of operations, you may as well use string concatenation. From Java 6 the performance has greatly improved.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/java-stringbuilder-myth-debunked.html

http://www.code-thrill.com/2012/08/stringbuilder-optimizations-demystified.html

Comment: Both your links state that it's better to use StringBuilder. The links are good, but your answer contradicts them. What gives?

Comment: I should have pointed out that even though the article say use StringBuilder, the first one says do it because of JDK5 and the second one points to the reason to use StringBuilder when constructing strings using if statements or for loops. The way the poster uses strings he should stick with concatenation