# Concatenate or Merge strings (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, merge, concatenation

How can I Concatenate or Merge a string after another string in java?
for example I have this first string:

```
String1="12345"
```

and this is second string:

```
String2="00000"
```

How to concatenate the second string after first string? Output is:

```
String3="1234500000"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+` operator to concatenate them. Give your variables small first letters: `string1`

Plus operator for printing:

```
System.out.println(string1 + string2);
```

Or store in a third String (string3)

```
string3 = string1 + string2;
```

There is the `string1.concat(string2)`  function, but if there is a Null value it will `NPE`. Furthermore, the `concat()` method only accepts String values while the `+` operator will silently convert the argument to a String (using the `toString()` method for objects)
 [See here for more on Concat and +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator)

Comment: Is this operation stores string2 directly after string3?

Comment: What do you mean? `string3` will be `string1` followed by `string2` or as in your example "1234500000"

Comment: ???? That was downvoted already, I didn't touch the question at all! I went to the trouble of answering your question!

Comment: @MohammadFarahi No problem, my pleasure! I wouldn't downvote a question I've answered, and if I do downvote I add a comment saying why! Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following:

```
String string1 = "12345";
String string2 = "00000";

string1 += string2;

System.out.println(string1);
```

By doing it this way, you can eliminate the string3 variable.