# Can I combine multiple concat?

Tags: java, concatenation

I want to short my coding as much as I can. I tried to use "concat" but facing a problem to combine in multiple way. Did concat allow to combine two concat only (per concat)?

```
String concat1 = "Please Make A Choice :";
    String concat2 = "(1) For Calculate Area Of Circle";
    String concat3 = "(2) For Calculate Area Of Rectangle";
    String concat4 = "(3) For Calculate Area Of Triangle";
    String concat5 = concat1.concat(concat2,concat3,concat4);
```

Comment: Why not assigning a single String?

Comment: `String prompt = "Please Make A Choice :(1) For Calculate Area Of Circle(2) For Calculate Area Of Rectangle(3) For Calculate Area Of Triange"`

Comment: Just use `+` - `concat1 + concat2 + concat3 + concat4`.

Comment: not able to figure out .. Why using unnecessary concat?

Comment: I'm not prefer assign with single String only.. Seems like they have so many choice.. thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concat takes one String argument, and appends it to the String instance it's called on. See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) for the details.

You can use the + operator to do this

```
String concat5 = concat1+concat2+concat3+concat4;
```

But be aware that this is a relatively expensive process, and if you're doing a lot of concatenation the [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class is the thing to use instead.

Comment: Outside of a loop, the compiler will usually optimise to a `StringBuilder` anyway (`StringBuffer` is an older `synchronized` version and should be avoided). The `+` operator is shorthand for `concat`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider not quite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator

Comment: Okay, fair enough, it calls a nullsafe `toString`.

Comment: Please don't use `StringBuffer`; `StringBuilder` is essentially always preferable.

Comment: @Jon Kiparsky , sir.. what do you mean by " But be aware that this is a relatively expensive process, and if you're doing a lot of concatenation the StringBuffer class is the thing to use instead. ".. Im so sorry.. I'm new with coding..

Comment: @Edie Don't worry about that. `concat1 + concat2 + concat3 + concat4` is the right way to do it. It gets translated into `StringBuilder` by the Java compiler automatically, and so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @Edie then don't worry about it, it is a performance optimization that you don't have to worry about until performance becomes an issue. Also, in this scenario, the string is probably just interned, so it makes 0 difference.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young since they are all compile time constants, won't it just do it during compile?

Comment: @clcto .. Thanks for the explaination.. You guys so nice.. :)

Comment: @clcto They're only treated as constants if declared as static final fields. Not the case here in the OP's code.

Comment: @Edie yes, don't worry about it. For a small set of operations it's not going to make any difference. If you were looping over a large number of Strings and glomming them together, it would make a difference, since each + operation would create a new StringBuilder

Comment: @all - yes, I misspoke. StringBuilder, not StringBuffer. (I confess, I do get the two mixed up in my head... my bad)

Answer (score 1):

you can use + operator to concat Strings but if you need to use keyword `concat` then this is how

```
concat5=  concat1.concat(concat2).concat(concat3).concat(concat4);
```