# String concatenation gives wrong output in java

Tags: java

I'm reading some data from file.

```
String content = null;

    File file=new File(str);
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte byt[] = new  byte[1024];
    try {
        while(fis.read(byt)!=-1)
        {
            content += new String(byt);
        }
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

File contains some text say `Hello`.
when I read complete file it gives me string `nullHello`. why it is so. and when I set `content = ""` it gives me right string. 
In first case jvm will not any memory to content object then while concatenating how it uses null as string ?

Comment: Because `String content = null;`.

Comment: String content = "";

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator

Comment: Look into `StringBuilder`.  Building up strings by constructing `String`s and concatenating them causes a lot of memory trashing due to the creation of objects just to have them collected by automatic garbage collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [JLS - 15.18.1 String Concatenation Operator +](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1.1):

> If the reference is `null`, **it is converted to the string "null"** (four
>   ASCII characters n, u, l, l). Otherwise, the conversion is performed
>   as if by an invocation of the toString method of the referenced object
>   with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the toString method
>   is null, then the string "null" is used instead.

That's why you're getting `"null"` concatenated as a String, you probably want to initialize the variable to *empty* String, which is `""`.

It's highly advised to use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of `+`, when it comes to performance, you'll feel the difference.

Comment: but String class toString() return same String object. In declaration of string class there private final char value[]; and int hash is there.so how and why it convert to "null" string? why it allocate 4 byte to store "null" when user specified I will allocate memory later, till the time String object will not point to any memory location

Comment: I know I need to use "" but I have question why it allocate memory?

Comment: It convert to "null" because that's how the language is defined. Also declaring a variable to `null` reference doesn't mean that there's no memory allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String content = null;
```

with

```
String content = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in Java, a null String object can be concatenated to other strings.  A null String object will print "null."

An empty String object will print a 0-character string and that is why when you start with the empty string, it will print the correct string.

Answer (score 0):

```
String content = null;
```

This is clearly assigned by you only. Later you are concatenating  `null`+hello thats why it is giving nullhello as output.

So, keep `String content="";` instead of `String content=null`