# Ignoring upper/lowercase strings

Tags: java, substring

My goal is to change any form of the word "java" in a sentence to "JAVA".I've got everything done but my code won't read in mixed cases for example:JaVa, JAva,etc. I know I am suppose to use toUpperCase and toLowerCase or equalsIgnoreCase but I am not sure how to use it properly. I am not allowed to use replace or replace all, teacher wants substring method.

```
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence with words including java");
    String sentence=input.nextLine();

    String find="java";
    String replace="JAVA";
    String result="";
    int n;
    do{
        n=sentence.indexOf(find);
        if(n!=-1){
            result =sentence.substring(0,n);
            result=result +replace;
            result = result + sentence.substring(n+find.length());
            sentence=result;            
        }
    }while(n!=-1);
    System.out.println(sentence);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are allowed to use `toUpperCase()` ? try this one

```
 Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence with words including java");
    String sentence=input.nextLine();

    String find="java";
    String replace="JAVA";
    String result="";

    result = sentence.toLowerCase();
    result = result.replace(find,replace);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

reply with the result :))

**Update : Based on**

> I've got everything done but my code won't read in mixed cases for
>   example:JaVa, JAva,etc.

you can use your code

```
   Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence with words including java");
    String sentence=input.nextLine();

    String find="java";
    String replace="JAVA";
    String result="";
    int n;
    do{
        //for you to ignore(converts the sentence to lowercase) either lower or upper case in your sentence then do the nxt process
        sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();

        n=sentence.indexOf(find);
        if(n!=-1){
            result =sentence.substring(0,n);
            result=result +replace;
            result = result + sentence.substring(n+find.length());
            sentence=result;            
        }
    }while(n!=-1);
    System.out.println(sentence);
}
```

**Update 2 :** I put toLowerCase Convertion outside the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

            String sentence = "Hello my name is JAva im a jaVa Man with a jAvA java Ice cream";
            String find="java";
            String replace="JAVA";
            String result="";
            int n;
            //for you to ignore(converts the sentence to lowercase) either lower or upper case in your sentence then do the nxt process
            sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
            System.out.println(sentence);

            do{


                n=sentence.indexOf(find);
                if(n!=-1){
                    result =sentence.substring(0,n);
                    result=result +replace;
                    result = result + sentence.substring(n+find.length());
                    sentence=result;            
                }
            }while(n!=-1);

            System.out.println(sentence);
    }
```

**RESULT**

> hello my name is java im a java man with a java java ice cream
>
> hello my name is JAVA im a JAVA man with a JAVA JAVA ice cream

Comment: sorry! can't use replace, am only allowed to use substring method.

Comment: the updated part will not work because it will convert the whole sentence to lower case thus altering more than just string matching variations of "java"

Comment: what do you want to do with the sentence? i thought that you want to convert all (java, JavA, jaVa etc.. ) inside of your sentence to JAVA(uppercase).

Comment: I convert the sentence to lowercase to ignore the case sensitivity

Comment: @Secondo thank you so much! something as simple as that... Im still new to programming so I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Im Glad that i was able to help you :)) it would be great if i got my First Accepted Answer :) :P Happy Coding :)

Comment: Interesting.  The final answer is wrong of course, but we'll leave it for Ben's teacher / marker to point out the flaw.  :-)

Comment: @StephenC Hi sir im open for correction :) can you state why is it wrong ? so that if ever i can fix this TIA

Comment: @Secondo - See my updated answer.  You should be able to figure out your mistake from there.

Comment: @StephenC thanks bro +1 for explanation indeed you're right. im sorry i wasnt able to explain it to Ben

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that using `String.indexOf` because it is case sensitive.

The simple solution is to use a regex with a case insensitive pattern; e.g.

```
Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl);
```

That also has the benefit of avoiding the messy string-bashing you are currently using to do the replacement.

---

In your example, your input string is also valid as a regex ... because it doesn't include any regex meta-characters.  If it did, then the simple workaround is to use `Pattern.quote(str)` which will treat the meta-characters as literal matches.

It is also worth nothing that `String.replaceAll(...)` is a "convenience method" for doing a regex replace on a string, though you can't use it for your example because it does case sensitive matching.

---

For the record, here is a partial solution that does the job by string-bashing.  @ben - this is presented for you to read and understand ... not to copy.  It is deliberately uncommented to encourage you to read it carefully.

```
// WARNING ... UNTESTED CODE
String input = ...
String target = ...
String replacement = ...
String inputLc = input.lowerCase();
String targetLc = target.lowerCase();
int pos = 0;
int pos2;
while ((pos2 = inputLc.indexOf(targetLc, pos)) != -1) {
    if (pos2 - pos > 0) {
        result += input.substring(pos, pos2);
    }
    result += replacement;
    pos = pos2 + target.length();
}
if (pos < input.length()) {
    result += input.substring(pos);
}
```

It probably be more efficient to use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String` for `result`.

Comment: Sorry! forgot to mention I can't use replaceAll. Teacher wants me to use substring method only.

Comment: @Stephen C, there is a way to use `String.replaceAll` in a case-insensitive manner by including `"(?i)"`, as I've demonstrated in my answer

Comment: @ben - Actually, I expect your teacher wants you work out the whole thing for your self!!

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to remove your `do/while` loop entirely and just use a case-insensitive regex with `String.replaceAll()`, like:

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("(?i)java", "JAVA");
System.out.println(sentence);
```

Or, more general and according to your variable namings:

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("(?i)" + find, replace);
System.out.println(sentence);
```

[**Sample Program**](http://ideone.com/kjEuxA)

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments, if you need to use the substring method, here is one way.

First, since `String.indexOf` does case-sensitive comparisons, you can write your own case-insensitive method, let's call it `indexOfIgnoreCase()`. This method would look something like:

```
// Find the index of the first occurrence of the String find within the String str, starting from start index
// Return -1 if no match is found
int indexOfIgnoreCase(String str, String find, int start) {
    for(int i = start; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.substring(i, i + find.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(find)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Then, you can use this method in the following manner.

You find the index of the word you need, then you add the portion of the String before this word (up to the found index) to the result, then you add the replaced version of the word you found, then you add the rest of the String after the found word.

Finally, you update the starting search index by the length of the found word.

```
String find = "java";
String replace = "JAVA";
int index = 0;
while(index + find.length() <= sentence.length()) {
    index = indexOfIgnoreCase(sentence, find, index);       // use the custom indexOf method here
    if(index == -1) {
        break;
    }
    sentence = sentence.substring(0, index) +               // copy the string up to the found word
               replace +                                    // replace the found word
               sentence.substring(index + find.length());   // copy the remaining part of the string
    index += find.length();
}
System.out.println(sentence);
```

[**`Sample Program`**](http://ideone.com/5JHGsw)

You could use a `StringBuilder` to make this more efficient since the `+` operator creates a new String on each concatenation.  [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator)

Furthermore, you could combine the logic in the `indexOfIgnoreCase` and the rest of the code in a single method like:

```
String find = "java";
String replace = "JAVA";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;
while(i + find.length() <= sentence.length()) {
    // if found a match, add the replacement and update the index accordingly
    if(sentence.substring(i, i + find.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(find)) {
        sb.append(replace);
        i += find.length();
    } 
    // otherwise add the current character and update the index accordingly
    else {
        sb.append(sentence.charAt(i));
        i++;
    }
}
sb.append(sentence.substring(i)); // append the rest of the string
sentence = sb.toString();
System.out.println(sentence);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you are "normalizing" the inter-word spacing as a side effect.  Also, it won't work if there is a punctuation character immediately before or after the `find` word.

Comment: yes you are correct, i figured out a much better solution

Comment: Sorry! forgot to mention I can't use replaceAll. Teacher wants me to use substring method only.

Comment: @ben, check out my edit. I believe it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @nem thank you for all your help! Unfortunately, I haven't learned indexOfIgnoreCase and I'm not allowed to use stringbuilder either(my fault for not stating more clearly on my directions, running out of time atm)so I couldn't use any of your suggestions. Really appreciate the help!