# Trying to understand the print order of b.h and b.getH() in this code

Tags: java

I want to know why the following code prints:

```
Beta 44
44 44
```

Please correct me because my analysis is apparently not correct but I cannot figure out why.

`b.h` gets called first, and it is 44 then b.getH() is called and it prints "Beta 44". So the console          prints `44 Beta 44`. Why is it not the case?

```
public class Beta {

    public int h = 44;
    public int getH(){
        System.out.println("Beta "+h);
        return h;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Beta b = new Beta();
        System.out.println(b.h+" "+ b.getH());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println(b.h+" "+ b.getH());
```

[is equivalent to (YMMV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator)

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String result = builder.append(b.h).append(" ").append(b.getH()).toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

As you can see, though `b.h` is evaluated first, it is not printed until the whole `String` value is constructed from the concatenation. That construction involves invoking `b.get()` which has its own

```
System.out.println("Beta "+h);
```

Answer (score 2):

To run the line `System.out.println(b.h+" "+ b.getH());` in `main`, it is necessary to call `b.getH` first, and then `System.out.println`.

The first line of your output comes from the call to `b.getH` (in particular, from the `System.out.println` *inside* that method).  The second line comes from the enclosing call to `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 2):

Java must evaluate all necessary arguments before operators perform their operation.

In this case, `b.getH()` is called before `b.h + " "` gets concatenated to the result of `b.getH()`.

Here,

1. `b.h` is concatenated to `" "` to yield `"44 "`.
2. `b.getH()` is called.
3. `getH()` prints `"Beta 44"`.
4. `getH()` returns `44`.
5. `44` gets concatenated to the end of `"44 "` from step (1), yielding `"44 44"`, which is now printed.

Answer (score 2):

> `b.h` gets called first

`b.h` is a field, not a method, so it cannot be "called". Your code *reads* the value from it, gets 44, and saves it for the time being; **nothing gets printed yet.**

> then `b.getH()` is called and it prints "Beta 44"

That's right - this is how you get the first line, i.e. `"Beta 44"`

> So the console prints `44 Beta 44`

That is not what the console should print, because `"Beta 44"` from inside `getH()` must finish printing *before* `b.h+" "+ b.getH()` starts to print.

The console cannot start printing `b.h+" "+ b.getH()` before getting both parts. Once `b.getH()` returns, `println` has all the parts ready, i.e. 44 obtained from reading `b.h`, the space to put in between, and finally the 44 to print at the end. Hence, `"44 44"` gets printed on the second line.

Answer (score 1):

First `b.h+" "+ b.getH()` has to evaluate before it can be printed. Based on your expected output, you could have done something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Beta b = new Beta();
    System.out.print(b.h);
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println(b.getH());
}
```

Your existing version is equivalent to

```
String temp = b.h+" "+ b.getH();
System.out.println(temp);
```