# How to combine two strings in Java

Tags: java, string

I am receiving two strings in one second from a remote device via bluetooth. (1st string then after some millisecond the 2nd string). for example:

```
string 1: 56ab5620a12031456764610000000000
```

and

```
string 2: 56ab563012800.
```

How and where should I store my first string, wait for next string and then combine these two like head+block? any suggestion please.

Comment: whats the expected output after combining? do you want do a normal concatenation operation?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: the expected output should be like this: 56ab5620a1203145676461000000000056ab563012800

Comment: I wonder why this question marked as duplicate. I am receiving two strings in one seconds..one after another. and these strings are continously coming from a remote device. the problem is how and where I store 1st string and wait for another and then make a new string. this was my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate or sum the `Strings`:

```
String combined = string1 + string2;
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Just use concatenation ( + ) sign.