# String concatenation concat() and + operator usage effectively

Tags: java, coding-style, string-concatenation

I am aware of [String concatenation: concat() vs "+" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator)

But i have question on usage of both concat() and + operator effectively

`concat()` is more efficient than `+` operator but still we are using `+` operator in few cases below

**Case 1**

```
System.out.println("Hi! Welcome: "+nameString);
```

**Case 2:**

splitting huge length line in to multiple lines(eclipse formatting)

```
System.out.println("Hi! Welcome: "+nameString1
                                  +nameString2
                                  +nameString3);
```

why still we are using `+` operator instead of `concat()`?

Comment: Q: Why should we be using `"Hello".concat("World").concat("!")` instead of `"Hello" + "World" + "!"`? A: There's no reason to do so, because it's much more concise and readable using `+`, and the possible performance penalty is absolutely no issue 99.99999% of the time.

Comment: In fact, as @JordiCastilla pointed out, in real life, if you're worried about performance, you'll use StringBuilder anyway, which probably scales better when concat'ing more than two strings.

Comment: The `+` operation is applied in compile-time if possible.

Comment: Hope [this][1] answers your question 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's are difference.

If `aStr` is null, then `aStr.concat(bStr)` >>  `NPE`s 
but if `aStr += bStr` will treat the original value of `aStr` as if it were `null`.

Also, the `concat()` method accepts just `String` instead the `+` operator which converts the argument to `String` (with `Object.toString()`).

So the `concat()` method is more strict in what it accepts.

Also, if you have lot of String concatenations with `concat()` or `+`, I highly recommend to work with mutable [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object that will increase speed of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you about concat() efficiency, but look into few issue with it,

For concat(String str)

concat() is more strict about its argument means it only accept String not any other primitive or wrapper data type (Signature concat(String str)).
String a = null, String b = "ABC"; b.concat(a) Throw null pointer exception.

for +
accept all data type(wrapper or primitive) where as if you work with a+=b there wont any NPE
operator will silently convert the argument to a String (using the toString() method for objects)