# (Java) What is the point of using `concat()`?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

From my knowledge, I know I can use `concat()` in such manner:

```
String str = "to";
System.out.println(str.concat("gether")
```

Which returns `together`.
But isn't that just like saying `str + "gether"`?

Why make a method for it when you can just use `+` to join `Strings` together?

Does it serve any other purpose?

Comment: Have you tried decompiling the result of `System.out.println(str + "gether")`? Without a suitable method, what would you expect the bytecode to look like? (It could use `StringBuilder`, but that would be a bit of a waste...)

Comment: Someone posted a good explanation already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator