# How does '+' operator overloading for non-primitive types work in java?

Tags: java, oop

Strings obviously can be concatinated, and primitive number types anyway. Also, one can concatinate paths and strings, and such. How does this work in java internally? Is there some hidden c++-like operator definition?

Comment: You can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator. When you concatenate strings with other objects, `String.valueOf()` method is applied to each non-string object to transform it to string

Comment: is the tag **polymorphism** necessary ??

Answer (score 2):

There is no operator overloading in Java. All of this is internal to the compiler.

When Java compiler translates your program, it knows compile-time type of each expression and sub-expression. When it sees a `+` with a `String` expression on one side, it applies string concatenation. When it sees two different types, it applies type promotion rules, and so on. This process is similar to overload resolution in languages that support operator overloading, but it is entirely hidden from the programmers using the language.

Answer (score 0):

The + operator works as an Additive Operator or  String Concatenation Operator. The selection depends on the operands i.e if they are of primitive number types e.g: int, short, long, float, double etc. the java compiler performs additive operation. However, if any of the operand is string, then it performs concatenation.
15.18.1 String Concatenation Operator +
If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11)
is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.
The result of string concatenation is a reference to a String object that is the
concatenation of the two operand strings. The characters of the left-hand operand
precede the characters of the right-hand operand in the newly created string.
The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a constant
expression (§15.28).
An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step
to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate String object. To increase the
performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer
class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are
created by evaluation of an expression.
For primitive types, an implementation may also optimize away the creation of a wrapper
object by converting directly from a primitive type to a string.
[Link][http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#39990] Page 564

Comment: direct link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1