# I want to add 00 before a number take for example 1 in JSP .like 1 to 001?

Tags: jsp

I want to add 00 before a int example 1.How can i do that.I know that there is a way to do that using if condition and then concat() but i want a cleaner method for converting 1 to 001.

Comment: you want to change it to decimal 1,00 or you want 100 ?

Comment: Create a static utility method in Java doing what you want. Register it as a JSP EL function in a JSP tag library. Invoke the JSP EL function from the JSP. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaio

Comment: Or just use `00${theValue}`, if that's what you want.

Comment: I want to change it to 001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% 
int i =1;
String s = "00"+i+"";
out.println(s);
%>
```

you can do it by this in jsp tag

Comment: Thanks it worked but I think that the int i was converted to string.I want just that.Is that true??

Comment: yes '+' do concat and convert to String
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with javascript

example

```js
function myFunction() {

   var num = 15;
      var n = num.toString();

    var str2 = "00";
    var res = n.concat(str2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: can I use javascript on server side

Comment: if you want to do it on server side then just use simple java code