# Java - double and integer

Tags: java

Q. What is the output after executing the following code snippet?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                              
    double a = 6;                                                                                     
    int b = 4;
    System.out.println("The passcode is " + a + b);
}
```

I am new to this programming language JAVA, thus from my understanding, I thought the answer should be "

> The passcode is 10"

however the answer is

> "The passcode is 6.04"

Can anyone help me resolve my doubt?

Comment: the answer of that question can be tested by yourself ... no need a community to get an answer like that...

Comment: You are concatenating `a` and `b` to the string "The passcode is ", you are not adding `a` and `b`. Just play around a little bit and you'll see. Cheers.

Comment: try System.out.println("The passcode is " + (a + b));

Comment: You can [test it and see it live **here**](https://ideone.com/JFCRJX), it's a String concatenation.

Comment: Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7 then that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator

Comment: Good question. In this respect Java is seriously broken. (The string on the left hand side puts `+` into some sort of weird concatenation mode and the `toString()` method is essentially called for all other arguments, with yet another kludge for primitive types which themselves are kludges anyway) It's a pity you've stumbled upon one of its many shortcomings so soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact this is a **[`String` concatenation](https://www.javatpoint.com/string-concatenation-in-java)**, so you will get the following result:

> The passcode is 6.04

Because the statement is evaluated as : `"The passcode is "+"6.0"+"4"`.

Because here both the `double` and `int` value are interpreted as `strings` in the concatenation, as the expression is evaluated from left to right.

What you need to write in order to avoid this is:

```
System.out.println("The passcode is " + (int)(a + b));
```

Where `(a+b)` will be a `double`, then we cast it to `int` with the following `(int)`.

You can check this **[live demo here](https://ideone.com/JFCRJX)** to see the difference between both of them.

Comment: the need to write statement still result into expected output... [`10` vs `10.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46466533/1746118)

Comment: @nullpointer well pointed out, I updated it, I just wanted to point out the situation here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
System.out.println("The passcode is " + (a + b)); //10.0
//concatenates the double value to string after manipulation
```

or

```
System.out.println("The passcode is " + (int)(a + b)); //10
//concatenates the int value to string after manipulation
```

instead of

```
System.out.println("The passcode is " + a + b); 
// concatenates all the arguments to string moving left to right to start with " " +
```

Comment: Haven't downvoted but I think your answer won't help the OP. Since his question is so elementary basic, I think it he'd learn more if you'd give him some information or maybe links so he can find it out himself.

Comment: your answer is OK but I do not understand how some people just want to vote down any one.

Answer (score -1):

Variable `a` is a `double`, so `6` becomes `6.0`.

The `+` operator with a `String` doesn't operate an addition but a concatenation. Java converts automatically your `double` and `int` scalar types to `String`'s.

Your result is like:

```
"The passcode is " + "6.0" + "4"
```

Which outputs:

> The passcode is 6.04

Comment: your answer is OK but I do not understand how some people just want to vote down any one.