# How to add new text to string without removing old string text?

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have a string `String text = "";` and I add a text to it

```
text = "Apple";
```

now I want it not to remove the old String when I add a new one, like this

```
text = "Banana";
text = "Orange";
```

The output should be `Apple, Banana, Orange`, but the output i'm getting is `Orange`. **How to do that in java?**

Comment: you can use StringBuilder

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String concatenation: concat() vs "+" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since String is Immutable then you can't edit t without reassigning it, however there is something called StringBuilder it is mutable so it can be changed.

```
String original=new String("blabla")
StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder(myString);
```

original will not be affected expect if did you re assign it, but because of String builder is mutable you can do something like the following

```
builder.appened("someData");
```

and it should be retrieved as string like this

```
String newString=builder.toString()
```

Comment: the out put i need `blabla, someData` but i can't see that!

Comment: the output should be blablasomedata

Comment: `String original = new String("blabla");
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(original);
                        builder.append("someData");`

Comment: i'm getting `blablasomedata`

Comment: Yep exactly, but be aware that the original value was not changed so if you wrote System.out.println(orginal)
It will print blabla

Comment: actually that doesn't solve my problem, i'm using json (async task) and the string come from array `items[] : { "string: "bla1" },{ "string: "bla2" },{ "string: "bla3" }` now on result i want to catch it in a single string like `bla1bla2bla3` i thought i'll get this result but i won't

Comment: That wasnt what question asking for !

Answer (score 0):

You want the variable to hold multiple Strings. Yet, you don't want to append the String. A data structure is what you are looking for.

In this case, ArrayList can fulfill your needs:

```
ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
texts.add("Apple");
texts.add("Banana");
texts.add("Orange");
```

You can get the elemebt by the order you added the Strings with index beggining with 0:

```
Systen.out.println(texts.get(0));    // prints "Apple"
```

To print all the elements from the ArrayList:

```
System.out.println(texts);    // prints "Apple, Banana, Orange"
```

Comment: how to get all items together? `texts.get(all)` ??

Comment: result i need is `AppleBananaOrange`

Comment: texts itself is already a collection of all items, hence you don't need (and can't) get all items. To print all elements, just print the entire list. As shown in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can achieve your desired output/result:

**1. Using String:**

You can simply append the new values at the end of String as following...

```
String text = "";
text = "Apple";
text = text + ", "+ "Banana";
text = text + ", "+ "Orange";

System.out.println(text); //output will be: Apple, Banana, Orange
```

**2. Using StringBuilder: [recommended]**

You can initialize StringBuilder, and use append() function to append new values at the end of the String and at last, you can get `String` from `StringBuilder` using `toString()` method of `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
builder.append("Apple").append(", ").append("Banana").append(", ").append("Orange");

String text = builder.toString();

System.output.println(text); //output will be Apple, Banana, Orange
```

2nd approach is recommended because when you append a String in `StringBuilder`, it does not create new object of String in String pool every time, it updates the existing object of `StringBuilder`.

Whereas `String` class in Java is immutable, so when you append a String in String literal, then it does update the existing object, it does create new object of `String` in String pool and points the reference to newly created String pool object.