# Interpolation string from variable c#

Tags: c#, string, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate a string combined of two strings in C#. I have following code in VS 2015:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string username = "abc";
string mask = "{date:yy}/{username}";
```

What I want in result is:

```
18/abc
```

I know that I can interpolate it like:

```
mask = $"{date:yy}/{username}"
```

but mask is also an input. So i need something like:

```
string result = $"{mask}"
```

but the result is :

```
"{date:yy}/{username}"
```

Mask is actually downloaded from the database and in each case sequence of information can be different. 
I need to store in db whole mask and only complement it in code. I can't use String.Replace() method like

```
mask.Replace({date}, date.ToString())
```

because I need to have possibility to add some formatting like :yy, :yyyy, :dd etc.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String concatenation: concat() vs "+" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `in each case sequence of information can be different`? Please give us some examples

Comment: I think a better way to state your question would be like this:

string mask = "{date:yy}/{username}";
.... later ....
DateTime date = //something
string username = //something

string maskWithValues = HowDoIInterpolateThis(mask);

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/c-6-string-interpolation-is-not-a-templating-engine-and-it-s-not-the-new-string-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string.Format()` for that:

```
string mask = GetMaskFromDB(); //assume it returns "{0}/{1:yy}"
string username = "abc";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

var result = string.Format(mask, username, dt);
```

> Result: "abc/18"

References: **[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w2WW1N)**, **[String.Format Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2)**

Comment: In one case mask can be "{date}/{username}" but in other the order may change.

Comment: @Piotr In that case your mask will be like `"{1:yy}/{0}";`, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Sure [`string.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format)

```
string mask = string.Format("{0:yy}/{1}", date, username);
```

or [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

```
string mask = $"{date:yy}/{username}";
```

Comment: I didn't say precisely. Mask is downloaded from db and I should be generated automatically.

Comment: What I get from db is whole mask, but i can't use it like this:
string result = $"{mask}"