# How can i use Collections.sort to print a collection of words and print the first letter of the word

Tags: java, collections

I want to make something looked like an dictionary, where there are a lot of words starting with different letters. How can I use `Collections.sort()` so that I can sort all the words and print the info about the letters that are next. The result should look like:

```
Words starting by A:
AAA
AAB
ABB
ABC
Words starting by B:
BAA
BAB
BBB
BBC
```

That's my code:

```
public Dictionary(){
    private ArrayList<String> words;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        Collections.sort(words);
        String str = "";
        for(int i = 0; i< words.size() ; i++){
            str += words.get(i) + "\n";

        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please share your code?

Comment: I just edited my post, now it has the code

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend not using `Collections.sort()` on a filed in your `toString()` method. Beside that you should use a StringBuilder for your String generation. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47605/9662601) for more detailed information.

Beside that you can use a new variable to check if the next word starts with a different character:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    Collections.sort(words);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String startCharacter = null;
    for (String word : words) {
        if (startCharacter == null || !word.startsWith(startCharacter)) {
            startCharacter = word.substring(0, 1);
            result.append("Words starting by ").append(startCharacter).append(":\n");
        }
        result.append(word).append("\n");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Alternatively you can use the Java Stream API:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return words.stream()
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(word -> word.substring(0, 1), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.joining("\n")))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> "Words starting by " + e.getKey() + ": \n" + e.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

The result in both cases will be:

```
Words starting by A: 
AAA
AAB
ABB
ABC
Words starting by B: 
BAA
BAB
BBB
BBC
```