# Reference is not created while using + operator to concat two strings

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two strings, one string with some value and another with empty.

Example:

```
String string1="Great"
String string2="";
```

and concatenating these two string with concat function and + operator

Example:

```
 String cat=string1.concat(string2)
 String operator=string1+string2
```

As per my understanding, while using empty string in concat function as the string2 is empty no new reference will be created. But while using + operator a new reference will be created in the string pool constant. But in the below code while using the + operator new reference is not created.

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string1="Great",string2="";

        String cat=string1.concat(string2);
        if(string1==cat)
        {
            System.out.println("Same");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not same");
        }
        String operator=string1+string2;
        if(operator==string1)
            System.out.println("Same");
        else
            System.out.println("Not same");
    }
}
```

---

Output:

string 1 :69066349

cat :69066349

Same

string1 :69066349

operator :69066349

Not same

---

From the above code, as it's using + operator, the reference for the variable : operator should refer to the new memory, but it's pointing to the string1 reference. Please explain the above code.

Comment: String.hashCode() is a function of the value of the string, not its address

Comment: Ya, But I checked the address reference by debugging the code. hashCode is for my reference.

Comment: hashCode has nothing to do with the reference here, it is solely a function of the string value

Comment: Exactly, I removed the line now. My doubt is how "Not same" is printing for the second time instead of "Same"

Comment: it's because the two references are pointing to different objects in memory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String concatenation: concat() vs "+" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator)

Comment: No its pointing to the same reference, I checked the address by debugging. I mentioned it in the question. Read question carefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is all in the documentation.

For `String.concat`, the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) states this:

> If the length of the argument string is 0, then this `String` object is returned.

For the `+` operator, [JLS 15.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) states:

> The result of string concatenation is a reference to a `String` object that is the concatenation of the two operand strings. The characters of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the right-hand operand in the newly created string.
>
> The `String` object is newly created ([§12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)) unless the expression is a constant expression ([§15.29](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29)).

As you can see, the results will be different for the case where the 2nd string has length zero and this is not a constant expression.

That is what happens in your example.

---

You also said:

> But while using `+` operator a new reference will be created in the string pool constant.

This is not directly relevant to your question, but ... actually, no it won't be created there.  It will create a reference to a regular (not interned) `String` object in the heap.  (It would only be in the class file's constant pool ... and hence the string pool ... if it was a *constant expression*; see [JLS 15.29](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29))

Note that the string pool and the classfile constant pool are different things.

---

Can I add a couple of things:

- You probably shouldn't be using `String.concat`.  The `+` operator is more concise, and the JIT compiler should know how to optimize away the creation of unnecessary intermediate strings ... in the few cases where you might consider using `concat` for performance reasons.
- It is a bad idea to *exploit* the fact that no new object is created so that you can use `==` rather than `equals(Object)`.  Your code will be fragile.  Just use `equals` always for comparing `String` and the primitive wrapper types.  It is simpler and safer.

In short, the fact that you are even asking this question *suggests* that you are going down a blind alley.  Knowledge of this edge-case difference between `concat` and `+` is ... pointless ... unless you are planning to enter a quiz show for Java geeks.