# Java code hangs when try to compare huge files

Tags: java, performance

I am exploring an option to compare two files in Java and show the difference in html.

Below is the code, I am using -

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
 
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.LineIterator;
import org.apache.commons.text.diff.CommandVisitor;
import org.apache.commons.text.diff.StringsComparator;
 
public class FileDiff {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Read both files with line iterator.
        LineIterator file1 = FileUtils.lineIterator(new File("file-1.txt"), "utf-8");
        LineIterator file2 = FileUtils.lineIterator(new File("file-2.txt"), "utf-8");
 
        // Initialize visitor.
        FileCommandsVisitor fileCommandsVisitor = new FileCommandsVisitor();
 
        // Read file line by line so that comparison can be done line by line.
        while (file1.hasNext() || file2.hasNext()) {
            /*
             * In case both files have different number of lines, fill in with empty
             * strings. Also append newline char at end so next line comparison moves to
             * next line.
             */
            String left = (file1.hasNext() ? file1.nextLine() : "") + "\n";
            String right = (file2.hasNext() ? file2.nextLine() : "") + "\n";
 
            // Prepare diff comparator with lines from both files.
            StringsComparator comparator = new StringsComparator(left, right);
 
            if (comparator.getScript().getLCSLength() > (Integer.max(left.length(), right.length()) * 0.4)) {
                /*
                 * If both lines have atleast 40% commonality then only compare with each other
                 * so that they are aligned with each other in final diff HTML.
                 */
                comparator.getScript().visit(fileCommandsVisitor);
            } else {
                /*
                 * If both lines do not have 40% commanlity then compare each with empty line so
                 * that they are not aligned to each other in final diff instead they show up on
                 * separate lines.
                 */
                StringsComparator leftComparator = new StringsComparator(left, "\n");
                leftComparator.getScript().visit(fileCommandsVisitor);
                StringsComparator rightComparator = new StringsComparator("\n", right);
                rightComparator.getScript().visit(fileCommandsVisitor);
            }
        }
 
        fileCommandsVisitor.generateHTML();
    }
}
 
/*
 * Custom visitor for file comparison which stores comparison & also generates
 * HTML in the end.
 */
class FileCommandsVisitor implements CommandVisitor<Character> {
 
    // Spans with red & green highlights to put highlighted characters in HTML
    private static final String DELETION = "<span style=\"background-color: #FB504B\">${text}</span>";
    private static final String INSERTION = "<span style=\"background-color: #45EA85\">${text}</span>";
 
    private String left = "";
    private String right = "";
 
    @Override
    public void visitKeepCommand(Character c) {
        // For new line use <br/> so that in HTML also it shows on next line.
        String toAppend = "\n".equals("" + c) ? "<br/>" : "" + c;
        // KeepCommand means c present in both left & right. So add this to both without
        // any
        // highlight.
        left = left + toAppend;
        right = right + toAppend;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void visitInsertCommand(Character c) {
        // For new line use <br/> so that in HTML also it shows on next line.
        String toAppend = "\n".equals("" + c) ? "<br/>" : "" + c;
        // InsertCommand means character is present in right file but not in left. Show
        // with green highlight on right.
        right = right + INSERTION.replace("${text}", "" + toAppend);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void visitDeleteCommand(Character c) {
        // For new line use <br/> so that in HTML also it shows on next line.
        String toAppend = "\n".equals("" + c) ? "<br/>" : "" + c;
        // DeleteCommand means character is present in left file but not in right. Show
        // with red highlight on left.
        left = left + DELETION.replace("${text}", "" + toAppend);
    }
 
    public void generateHTML() throws IOException {
 
        // Get template & replace placeholders with left & right variables with actual
        // comparison
        String template = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("difftemplate.html"), "utf-8");
        String out1 = template.replace("${left}", left);
        String output = out1.replace("${right}", right);
        // Write file to disk.
        FileUtils.write(new File("finalDiff.html"), output, "utf-8");
        System.out.println("HTML diff generated.");
    }
}
```

For smaller files this works good and gives me good results on my laptop. But if file size is more (200MB) with half a million of rows then my IntelliJ seems to hang. RAM for my laptop is 16GB.

How can I improve this to handle large files for comparison?

Thanks

Comment: Use threads? Split the file into parts and compare each part in a separate thread.

Comment: @Abra How would threads help? This is file comparison, CPU usage should be dwarfed by disk usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote `FileCommandsVisitor` might cause it to fail to get optimized. What you're doing is adding strings for every character visited, for instance:

```
left = left + toAppend;
right = right + toAppend;
```

That might cause a new instance of a String to happen for every addition you do - new instance of a string that by the end is nearly 200 MB long. A new one for every character you visit. And old ones will need to get garbage collected. If your class held `StringBuilder`s instead, and you used `append()` method it might drastically speed up. For more details read [String concatenation: concat() vs "+" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator)

For clarity (since according to comments you missed the point twice now):

```
class FileCommandsVisitor implements CommandVisitor<Character> {

//StringBuilder as properties
private StringBuilder left = new StringBuilder();
private StringBuilder right = new StringBuilder();

@Override
public void visitKeepCommand(Character c) {
    String toAppend = "\n".equals("" + c) ? "<br/>" : "" + c;
    // append to the StringBuilders where you would concat strings
    left.append(toAppend);
    right.append(toAppend);
}

//same as above for other methods

..

public void generateHTML() throws IOException {

    String template = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("difftemplate.html"), "utf-8");
    //turn StringBuilders into Strings only when you actually need a String.
    String out1 = template.replace("${left}", left.toString());
    String output = out1.replace("${right}", right.toString());
    FileUtils.write(new File("finalDiff.html"), output, "utf-8");
    System.out.println("HTML diff generated.");
}
```

}

If that doesn't help however, and it was optimized at runtime - I don't see anything else fundamentally wrong with the way you're doing it. Comparing huge files is not a cheap operation, it won't be faster than the speed with which you can read two files line by line from your hard drive. You're still making a shortcut (that increases speed, not decreases) in having your `FileCommandsVisitor` hold both diffs in memory instead of writing it as it goes, which means that at best your code can diff a file of a size equal to half your available RAM. I note however, that you never mentioned how long it actually takes, so it's hard to say if the time you're seeing is expected or an anomaly.

Comment: After your last comment I gave it a run for comparison of  5MB files with 8k lines each. But even after 2 hours comparison is not completed.

Comment: And yes, that was after changing + to concat(). So that change doesn't change much in performance

Comment: @Abhi uh... no, not .concat(), that will also return a String instance every time you do it. You need to delay creating a String as long as you can by using `StringBuilders` as your properties and using the `append()` method to add to them, like I wrote in the answer

Comment: ohh sorry. I gave a run after changing + to 
        left=new StringBuilder().append(left).append(toAppend).toString();
        right=new StringBuilder().append(right).append(toAppend).toString();
but its still 2 hours and run is not completed.

Comment: @Abhi you missed my point again it seems, still creating a String every time in a method. I edited my answer to clearer explain what I mean.