# One liner javascript function to edit value of specific property from array of objects

Tags: javascript

Say, I have array of objects:

```
arr = [
    {path: 'mexico', name: 'mexico'},
    {path: 'brazil', name: 'brazil'},
    {path: 'netherlands', name: 'netherlands'}
];
```

What I want to achieve:

```
prefix = 'country/'
arr = [
    {path: 'country/mexico', name: 'mexico'},
    {path: 'country/brazil', name: 'brazil'},
    {path: 'country/netherlands', name: 'netherlands'}
];
```

Is there a one liner javascript function that append the prefix **country/** into the path property of all objects in the array?

perhaps, something like this: `arr.append(prefix, arr, 'path');`

Comment: You could just do something like `arr.forEach(x => x.path = "country/" + path)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `forEach` and a `concat`:

```js
arr = [
    {path: 'mexico', name: 'mexico'},
    {path: 'brazil', name: 'brazil'},
    {path: 'netherlands', name: 'netherlands'}
];
prefix = 'country/';
arr.forEach(x => x.path = prefix.concat(x.path));
console.log(arr);
```

**EDIT:**

Following what @MaikLowrey suggested on comment and reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47628/13897065) answer, `+` operator to concat strings has better performance and memory allocation compared to `concat` operator.

So the optimized solution is:

```js
    arr = [
        {path: 'mexico', name: 'mexico'},
        {path: 'brazil', name: 'brazil'},
        {path: 'netherlands', name: 'netherlands'}
    ];
    prefix = 'country/';
    arr.forEach(x => x.path = prefix + x.path);
    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Good solution but concat decrease your perfomance. better use `+`. `x.path = prefix + x.path)`

Comment: @MaikLowrey this is an intersting point of discussion. Unfortunately I'm not so expert to say which is the faster one. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47628/13897065) answer. Is quite old but it was updated on 2017. Before that date seems that `concat` works better with few strings, but on 2017 update seems that `+` got a small advantage in terms of performance and memory allocation. So yes, you are right. i will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It was only a hint. But if you work on scaled application it could be a point for optimization. ... and i like to discuss programming :-) Greetings & +1up!

Answer (score 2):

As mdn says about [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

So the code would be looked like that:

```
arr = arr.map(s => ({...s, path: 'country/' + s.path}))
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
    {path: 'mexico', name: 'mexico'},
    {path: 'brazil', name: 'brazil'},
    {path: 'netherlands', name: 'netherlands'}
];

arr = arr.map(s => ({...s, path: 'country/' + s.path}))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This should be a right answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr = [
    {path: 'mexico', name: 'mexico'},
    {path: 'brazil', name: 'brazil'},
    {path: 'netherlands', name: 'netherlands'}
];

prefix = "country/"

arr.forEach(entry => entry.path = prefix + entry.path)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would to use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like so:

```js
var prefix = 'country/';
var arr = [{
    path: 'mexico',
    name: 'mexico'
  },
  {
    path: 'brazil',
    name: 'brazil'
  },
  {
    path: 'netherlands',
    name: 'netherlands'
  }
];
arr.forEach(item => item.path = prefix + item.path);
console.log(arr);
```

You could also create your own somewhat generic function to do this for you

```js
var prefix = 'country/';
var arr = [{
    path: 'mexico',
    name: 'mexico'
  },
  {
    path: 'brazil',
    name: 'brazil'
  },
  {
    path: 'netherlands',
    name: 'netherlands'
  }
];
console.log(listPrepend(arr, "path", prefix));


function listPrepend(list, property, prefix) {
  return list.map(function(item) {
    item[property] = prefix + item[property];
    return item;
  });
}
```

You could also add some more logic to it

```js
var prefix = 'country/';
var arr = [{
    path: 'mexico',
    name: 'mexico',
    nested: {
      path: 'mexico'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'brazil',
    name: 'brazil',
    nested: {
      path: 'brazil'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'netherlands',
    name: 'netherlands',
    nested: {
      path: 'netherlands'
    }
  }
];
console.log(listPrepend(arr, "nested.path", prefix));


function listPrepend(list, propertyPath, prefix) {
  return list.map(function(item) {
    propertyPath.split(".").reduce(function(result, property, index, full) {
      var innerValue = result[property];
      if (index === full.length - 1) {
        result[property] = prefix + innerValue;
        return result;
      }
      return innerValue;
    }, item);
    return item;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All conceivable possibilities are already listed. Therefore here is a slightly different approach. Why fill your existing array with unnecessary redudant strings, when you can add the string in front in your loop. The advantage is not obvious in this example. If you have an array of more than just 195 countries, then you have unnecessarily included x times the prefix. Unnecessary power! ;-)

```js
const arr = [
    {path: 'mexico', name: 'mexico'},
    {path: 'brazil', name: 'brazil'},
    {path: 'netherlands', name: 'netherlands'}
  ];
const prefix = 'country/';

function setPath(row) {
  return  prefix + row.path;  
}

// in the loop
arr.forEach(row => console.log(setPath(row)))

// by index
console.log(`Here is the link to ${arr[1].name}: ${setPath(arr[1])}`)
```